# How to check for empty array in vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check for empty arrays. Google gave me varied solutions but nothing worked. Maybe I am not applying them correctly.

```
Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Email Signature
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
End Function

Dim FileNamesList As Variant, i As Integer
' activate the desired startfolder for the filesearch
FileNamesList = CreateFileList("*.*", False) ' Returns File names
' performs the filesearch, includes any subfolders
' present the result
' If there are Signatures then populate SigString
Range("A:A").ClearContents
For i = 1 To UBound(FileNamesList)
    Cells(i + 1, 1).Formula = FileNamesList(i)
Next i

SigString = FileNamesList(3)

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
    Signature = ""
End If
```

Here if `FileNamesList` array is empty, `GetBoiler(SigString)` should not get called at all. When `FileNamesList` array is empty, `SigString` is also empty and this calls `GetBoiler()` function with empty string. I get an error at line

```
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
```

since `sFile` is empty. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Check out [modArraySupport](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm), a useful set of procedures by Chip Pearson to support handling arrays. `IsArrayEmpty` does what you want.

Comment: If TypeName(FileNamesList) = "Empty" Then

Answer (score 80):

Go with a triple negative:

```
If (Not Not FileNamesList) <> 0 Then
    ' Array has been initialized, so you're good to go.
Else
    ' Array has NOT been initialized
End If
```

Or just:

```
If (Not FileNamesList) = -1 Then
    ' Array has NOT been initialized
Else
    ' Array has been initialized, so you're good to go.
End If
```

In VB, for whatever reason, `Not myArray` returns the SafeArray pointer. For uninitialized arrays, this returns -1. You can `Not` this to XOR it with -1, thus returning zero, if you prefer.

```
               (Not myArray)   (Not Not myArray)
Uninitialized       -1                 0
Initialized    -someBigNumber   someOtherBigNumber
```

[Source](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?654880-How-do-I-tell-if-an-array-is-quot-empty-quot&p=4040234&viewfull=1#post4040234)

Comment: Amazing solution. Never knew about this hack. Cheers!

Comment: Nice trick, +1 from me, but unfortunately I can not use this as part of a function, as I get Run-time error 13, type mismatch

`Function isArrayInitialized2(Arr As Variant) As Boolean`
`If (Not Arr) = -1 Then isArrayInitialized2 = False Else isArrayInitialized2 = True`
`End Function`

Comment: @nkatsar you need to pass Arr as Arr()

Answer (score 78):

As you are dealing with a string array, have you considered Join?

```
If Len(Join(FileNamesList)) > 0 Then
```

Comment: This is elegant and works with an empty array.

Comment: yeah it's short. but it potentially does a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: @VBOG Would you like to elaborate?

Comment: @Remou. Isn't `FileNamesList` an array? Shouldn't you use Ubound instead of Len?

Comment: @VBOG No, because JOIN has just created a string from the array.

Comment: I found that I had to add `""` as a delimiter argument to join, i.e. `If Len(Join(FileNamesList, "")) > 0 Then`

Comment: @Remou, UBound fails with a dirty a dirty "Subscript out of range" error. I really wish it returned -1

Comment: The catch is that this doesn't work if I have an array of empty strings...It's not really telling me if the array has been initialized.

Answer (score 29):

If you test on an array function it'll work for all bounds:

```
Function IsVarArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant)

Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(anArray,1)
If Err.number = 0 Then
    IsVarArrayEmpty = False
Else
    IsVarArrayEmpty = True
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Not bad, but try it on `arr` defined like this `Dim arr() As String : arr = Split("") : Debug.Print IsVarArrayEmpty(arr)`... This returns `False`, yet by all accounts, `arr` *is* an empty array (or what else would one call it?) with, oddly, `UBound(arr)=-1` and `LBound(arr)=0`. That gotcha is dealt with in Chip Pearson's [IsArrayEmpty](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm). That's why I linked to it in my comment to the question.

Comment: Sadly there is an undefined array, when UBound throws an error. There is also an empty array, where the length is found as in any other case: UBound(-1) - LBound(0) = 0

Comment: Hi, if you are on base 0 your array can add one element with index =0. That work if you dont set an array but not if you use redim arr(0). In this case your solution dont work. You need check if Ubound(arr) = 0 and len(Join(arr))=0. That is a part of @BBQ Chef response

Answer (score 7):

I see similar answers on here... but not mine...

This is how I am unfortunatley going to deal with it...  I like the len(join(arr)) > 0 approach, but it wouldn't work if the array was an array of emptystrings...

```
Public Function arrayLength(arr As Variant) As Long
  On Error GoTo handler

  Dim lngLower As Long
  Dim lngUpper As Long

  lngLower = LBound(arr)
  lngUpper = UBound(arr)

  arrayLength = (lngUpper - lngLower) + 1
  Exit Function

handler:
  arrayLength = 0 'error occured.  must be zero length
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

When writing VBA there is this sentence in my head: "Could be so easy, but..."

Here is what I adopted it to:

```
Private Function IsArrayEmpty(arr As Variant)
  ' This function returns true if array is empty
  Dim l As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  l = Len(Join(arr))
  If l = 0 Then
    IsArrayEmpty = True
  Else
    IsArrayEmpty = False
  End If

  If Err.Number > 0 Then
      IsArrayEmpty = True
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Private Sub IsArrayEmptyTest()
  Dim a As Variant
  a = Array()
  Debug.Print "Array is Empty is " & IsArrayEmpty(a)
  If IsArrayEmpty(a) = False Then
    Debug.Print "  " & Join(a)
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There are shorter discussions for checking an array for emptiness in assembly. It's just ridiculous.

Comment: @André Fratelli How I wish I could up-vote your comment

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't do what you expect:

```
If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString) 
Else
    Signature = "" 
End If
```

If you pass an empty string (`""`) or `vbNullString` to `Dir`, it will return the name of the first file in the current directory path (the path returned by `CurDir$`). So, if `SigString` is empty, your `If` condition will evaluate to `True` because `Dir` will return a non-empty string (the name of the first file in the current directory), and `GetBoiler` will be called. And if `SigString` is empty, the call to `fso.GetFile` will fail.

You should either change your condition to check that `SigString` isn't empty, or use the `FileSystemObject.FileExists` method instead of `Dir` for checking if the file exists. `Dir` is tricky to use precisely because it does things you might not expect it to do. Personally, I would use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` over `Dir` because there's no funny business (`FileExists` returns `True` if the file exists, and, well, `False` if it doesn't). What's more, `FileExists` expresses the *intent* of your code much clearly than `Dir`.

**Method 1: Check that `SigString` is non-empty first**

```
If SigString <> "" And Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString) 
Else
    Signature = "" 
End If
```

**Method 2: Use the `FileSystemObject.FileExists` method**

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FileExists(SigString) Then
    Signature = GetBoiler(SigString) 
Else
    Signature = "" 
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

I am simply pasting below the code by the great Chip Pearson. It works a charm.
Here's his [page on array functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm).

I hope this helps.

```
Public Function IsArrayEmpty(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' IsArrayEmpty
' This function tests whether the array is empty (unallocated). Returns TRUE or FALSE.
'
' The VBA IsArray function indicates whether a variable is an array, but it does not
' distinguish between allocated and unallocated arrays. It will return TRUE for both
' allocated and unallocated arrays. This function tests whether the array has actually
' been allocated.
'
' This function is really the reverse of IsArrayAllocated.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim LB As Long
    Dim UB As Long

    err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsArray(Arr) = False Then
        ' we weren't passed an array, return True
        IsArrayEmpty = True
    End If

    ' Attempt to get the UBound of the array. If the array is
    ' unallocated, an error will occur.
    UB = UBound(Arr, 1)
    If (err.Number <> 0) Then
        IsArrayEmpty = True
    Else
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' On rare occasion, under circumstances I
        ' cannot reliably replicate, Err.Number
        ' will be 0 for an unallocated, empty array.
        ' On these occasions, LBound is 0 and
        ' UBound is -1.
        ' To accommodate the weird behavior, test to
        ' see if LB > UB. If so, the array is not
        ' allocated.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        err.Clear
        LB = LBound(Arr)
        If LB > UB Then
            IsArrayEmpty = True
        Else
            IsArrayEmpty = False
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: RE: "On rare occasion, under circumstances I cannot reliably replicate, Err.Number will be 0 for an unallocated, empty array"; this occurs when an empty array is generated with arr=array()

Answer (score 2):

Simplified check for Empty Array:

```
Dim exampleArray() As Variant 'Any Type

If ((Not Not exampleArray) = 0) Then
      'Array is Empty
Else
      'Array is Not Empty
End If
```

Comment: This is the only way to do this that I can find without trapping the error. Unbelievable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do it. I have used it in some cases and it's working.

```
Function IsArrayEmpty(arr As Variant) As Boolean

Dim index As Integer

index = -1
    On Error Resume Next
        index = UBound(arr)
    On Error GoTo 0

If (index = -1) Then IsArrayEmpty = True Else IsArrayEmpty = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Function IsVarArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant) as boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsVarArrayEmpty = true
    IsVarArrayEmpty = UBound(anArray) < LBound(anArray)
End Function
```

Maybe `ubound` crashes and it remains at true, and if `ubound < lbound`, it's empty

Answer (score 2):

Based on ahuth's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382846/425678);

```
Function AryLen(ary() As Variant, Optional idx_dim As Long = 1) As Long
    If (Not ary) = -1 Then
        AryLen = 0
    Else
        AryLen = UBound(ary, idx_dim) - LBound(ary, idx_dim) + 1
    End If
End Function
```

Check for an empty array; `is_empty = AryLen(some_array)=0`

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function IsEmptyArray(InputArray As Variant) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
   IsEmptyArray = Not (UBound(InputArray) >= 0)
   Exit Function

   ErrHandler:
   IsEmptyArray = True

End Function
```

Comment: If you're going that route, you *have* to test `UBound > LBound`. In VBA you can have an array index running, e.g., `-5321 To -4112`. Just one of the language's "fun" quirks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below function to check if variant or string array is empty in vba

```
Function IsArrayAllocated(Arr As Variant) As Boolean
        On Error Resume Next
        IsArrayAllocated = IsArray(Arr) And _
                           Not IsError(LBound(Arr, 1)) And _
                           LBound(Arr, 1) <= UBound(Arr, 1)
End Function
```

Sample usage

```
Public Function test()
Dim Arr(1) As String
Arr(0) = "d"
Dim x As Boolean
x = IsArrayAllocated(Arr)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be to do it sooner.  You can create a Boolean variable and set it to true once you load data to the array.  so all you really need is a simple if statement of when you load data into the array.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a Byte array is empty, the simplest way is to use the VBA function `StrPtr()`.

If the Byte array is empty, `StrPtr()` returns `0`; otherwise, it returns a non-zero value (however, it's **not** the address to the first element).

```
Dim ar() As Byte
Debug.Assert StrPtr(ar) = 0

ReDim ar(0 to 3) As Byte
Debug.Assert StrPtr(ar) <> 0
```

However, it only works with Byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I'll generalize the problem and the Question as intended.
Test assingment on the array, and catch the eventual error

```
Function IsVarArrayEmpty(anArray as Variant)
Dim aVar as Variant

IsVarArrayEmpty=False
On error resume next
aVar=anArray(1)
If Err.number then '...still, it might not start at this index
    aVar=anArray(0)
    If Err.number then IsVarArrayEmpty=True ' neither 0 or 1 yields good assignment
EndIF
End Function
```

Sure it misses arrays with all negative indexes or all > 1... is that likely? in weirdland, yes.

Comment: If it doesn't work in weirdland, then it isn't "generalized".

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think one of the answers above can be modified to check if the array has contents:

```
if UBound(ar) > LBound(ar) Then
```

This handles negative number references and takes less time than some of the other options.

Comment: Fails for unallocated arrays (not `ReDim`ed) as well as for arrays that happen to have one element only. Also this is pretty much plagiarized from other (incorrect) answers to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the array is empty by retrieving total elements count using JScript's `VBArray()` object (works with arrays of variant type, single or multidimensional):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim a() As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim c As Long

    ' Uninitialized array of variant
    ' MsgBox UBound(a) ' gives 'Subscript out of range' error
    MsgBox GetElementsCount(a) ' 0

    ' Variant containing an empty array
    b = Array()
    MsgBox GetElementsCount(b) ' 0

    ' Any other types, eg Long or not Variant type arrays
    MsgBox GetElementsCount(c) ' -1

End Sub

Function GetElementsCount(aSample) As Long

    Static oHtmlfile As Object ' instantiate once

    If oHtmlfile Is Nothing Then
        Set oHtmlfile = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        oHtmlfile.parentWindow.execScript ("function arrlength(arr) {try {return (new VBArray(arr)).toArray().length} catch(e) {return -1}}"), "jscript"
    End If
    GetElementsCount = oHtmlfile.parentWindow.arrlength(aSample)

End Function
```

For me it takes about 0.3 mksec for each element + 15 msec initialization, so the array of 10M elements takes about 3 sec. The same functionality could be implemented via `ScriptControl` ActiveX (it is not available in 64-bit MS Office versions, so you can use workaround like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134477/2165759)).

Comment: Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/183353/2165759) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4097021/2165759) questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Ubound(yourArray)>-1 then
 debug.print "The array is not empty"
else
 debug.print "EMPTY"
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check its count.

Here **cid** is an array.

```
if (jsonObject("result")("cid").Count) = 0 them
MsgBox "Empty Array"
```

I hope this helps.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Another solution to test for empty array

```
if UBound(ar) < LBound(ar) then msgbox "Your array is empty!"
```

Or, if you already know that LBound is 0

```
if -1 = UBound(ar) then msgbox "Your array is empty!"
```

This may be faster than join(). (And I didn't check with negative indexes)

Here is my sample to filter 2 string arrays so they do not share same strings.

```
' Filtering ar2 out of strings that exists in ar1

For i = 0 To UBound(ar1)

    ' filter out any ar2.string that exists in ar1
    ar2 = Filter(ar2 , ar1(i), False)    

    If UBound(ar2) < LBound(ar2) Then
       MsgBox "All strings are the same.", vbExclamation, "Operation ignored":
       Exit Sub

    End If

Next

' At this point, we know that ar2 is not empty and it is filtered 
'
```

Comment: UBound will fail if the array is empty, it won't return -1 or one-less-than-lbound

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Function arrayIsEmpty(arrayToCheck() As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Err:
    Dim forCheck
    forCheck = arrayToCheck(0)
    arrayIsEmpty = False
    Exit Function
Err:
    arrayIsEmpty = True
End Function
```

Comment: Fails for non-zero-based arrays e.g.  `ReDim arrayToCheck(1 To 10)`.