# VBA CreateObject can’t create ActiveX component on 64Bit Windows

Tags: vba, dll, com, activex, 32bit-64bit

I have to write a program in Visual Studio 2013, but it doesn't work, so I started testing all the possibilities with Microsoft Excel and its developement playground. I started with the following version (provided by the company supplying the program I need to use):

```vb
Sub Main()

    Dim XServer As X2000.Server
    Dim XApp As X2000.Application
    Dim XSR As X2000.ScriptRoutines

    Set XServer = New X2000.Server
    Set XApp = XServer.AppConnection()    '<- This actually fires the application
    XApp.Visible = True

    Set XSR = XApp.ScriptCommands
    XSR.DATA_FILENAME = "C:\X2000\myFile.x"    ' <- Code blocks here

End Sub
```

This basically starts the application X2000.exe, connects my code to it, and then executes the `DATA_FILENAME` assignation routine, by loading  `myFile.x` in the program. I need to start the application, because at that point its license is checked, and I don't have any other option to work with.

Now, in this version, the code was blocking at the last line by saying "A dll is missing" without any other information. I tried late-binding the `ScriptRoutines` object by doing the following:

```vb
Dim XServer As X2000.Server
Dim XApp As X2000.Application
Dim XSR As Object

Set XServer = New X2000.Server
Set XApp = XServer.AppConnection()
XApp.Visible = True

XSR = CreateObject("XApp.ScriptCommands")
```

This doesn't work as well, but did give me a piece of information more: "ActiveX control couldn’t load the object". I did a little research, and found out, through "Dependancy Walker", that `X2000.exe` was depending on `MSVBVM60.DLL`, which was missing in the `system32` folder. Curious though, because my system is 64bit, Excel is too, and I tried the code on VS2013 by using a 32bit compatibility and still the code didn't work.
I installed [the service pack from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417), where this file was contained, only to find out, that `system32` was left untouched... 
`sysWoW64` instead had already a `MSVBVM60.DLL`, therefore I suspected that `X2000.exe` was written only to work with 32bit systems: I was wrong.

A colleague of mine could execute the same program written in MATLAB code:

```matlab
function [Data,eng_or_met] = Read_X2000_File_BB_2(sFileName)

XServer = actxserver('X2000.server');
XApp = XServer.AppConnection;
XApp.Visible = 1;
objX2000 = XApp.ScriptCommands;
objX2000.data_filename = "C:\X2000\myFile.x";

delete(XServer);
```

This code works thanks to the [`actxserver` function](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), which I believe to handle this compatibility problem.

How can I do the same with Excel/VS2013?

**EDIT:**

I tried with the code suggested by omegastripes:

```vb
Dim XSR As Object
Set XSR = CreateObjectx86("XApp.ScriptCommands") ' create ActiveX via x86 mshta host
```

being `CreateObjectx86` the function [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725882/getting-scriptcontrol-to-work-with-excel-2010-x64/38134477#38134477). I tried both the `If / Else` conditions and at the end the object is not created anyway, both with:

```vb
Set CreateObjectx86 = oWnd.CreateObjectx86(sProgID)
```

and

```vb
Set CreateObjectx86 = CreateObject(sProgID)
```

The last line is what gets executed if I don't change the code (therefore not `#If Win64`).

**EDIT:**

As per the first answer to this question, I also tried:

```vb
Dim XServer As Object
Dim XApp As X2000.Application
Dim XSR As X2000.Script

Set XServer = CreateObject("X2000.Server")
Set XApp = XServer.AppConnection()
XApp.Visible = True
Set XSR = X2000.ScriptCommands
```

Only to find out I get the same error.

Comment: Chances are actxserver is doing exactly the same thing but the context is different. If your app was written using VB6, then you must have MSVBVM60.dll somewhere. Run this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417 also check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2009/12/30/development-is-visual-basic-6-0-runtime-still-supported/ and if your app was built using a localized version of VB6, make sure you install localized VB6 support binaries

Comment: *I installed the service pack from Microsoft, where this file was contained* <- I already ran the file you linked me to. I cannot be sure that `X2000` was made with localized VB6, but it it were, I'd guess that'd be the standard version, that comes with every VB6, since the company providing `X2000` is from U.S.A.

Comment: if it's from USA, I don't think you'd need anything localized indeed. What I would do is use sysinternal's procmon tool and monitor files (filter by your program's exe name). This could help you determine the missing ones. It may be a satellite file, or one you didn't think of.

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I guess I could try... if I only were an admin -_-

Comment: @Noldor130884 I guess you are testing with 64-bit Office version, while MATLAB is 32-bit version, and ActiveX is written for 32-bit applications only, so it's working in MATLAB on x64 OS via WoW64. You may try late binding using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38134477/2165759).

Comment: @omegastripes I am not really sure (right now I cannot check), but I think MATLAB too should be 64bit. Anyway, could you elaborate on that solution? I don't think I understood how to create a `X2000.Server` with that late binding...

Comment: Checked: MATLAB too is 64bit

Comment: I'm aware you've found a workaround. I *think* I know what the issue is. But first, three questions in order to check. 1) Is a UAC prompt displayed when you run the first version of your code? 2) Does copying `MSVBVM60.DLL` from `sysWoW64` to `system32` enable the code to run correctly? 3)  Does your workaround still work using `Dim XApp As X2000.Application`?

Comment: Well, I'm all ears :) I always appreciate someone who can teach me something. About your questions: 1) No UAC prompt is displayed. 2) No. I tried that before already. Dependancy Walker highlighted several DLL not found at that point. 3) No it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently solved the issue. Inspired by Hans Passant, I `Dim`ed the `XServer` as the only object depending on the reference to X2000.exe:

```
Dim XServer As X2000.Server
Dim XApp As Object
Dim XSR As Object

Set XServer = New X2000.Server
Set XApp = XServer.AppConnection
XApp.Visible = True
Set XSR = XApp.ScriptCommands

XSR.DATA_FILENAME = "C:\foo.x"
```

`DATA_FILENAME` is actually a "ScriptCommand" that gets executed.

Simple as that. Yet I have no idea why this works.