# How to get, JSON values to Work in VBA-JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba, parsing

I am trying to access nested JSON values that come back from the API that I am working with at the moment. There seem to be no field names to use in this JSON, making it very difficult to follow most examples online.

API URL - [CLICK HERE](https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:5m:tEOSUSD/hist?start=1535760000000&end=1538265600000&sort=1)

I am using [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) through this process, and I've got it to successfully display "responseText" in MsgBox.

I am looking for a way to make this code work.

```
Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:5m:tEOSUSD/hist?start=1535760000000&end=1538265600000&sort=1", False
    http.Send
    Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
    i = 2
    For Each Item In JSON
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("one")  ' Items reference as an example
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("two")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("three")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("four")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("five")
        i = i + 1
    Next
    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Item(1)` etc.  If that doesn't help then please update your question to describe exactly what happens when you run your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my answer to [Using VBA and VBA-JSON to access JSON data from Wordpress API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128453/9912714)
, I wrote a function, `PrintJSONAccessors()`, which breaks down how to access the data in a JSON structure.

Checking the JSON object in the Locals Window reveals that it consists of a collection of collections.

[image]

Checking the TypeName of the item in the Immediate Window also reveals that item is indeed a collection'

```
?TypeName(Item)
Collection
```

> ```
> PrintJSONAccessors JSON, "?JSON"
> ```

The code will output the correct way to access the data

[image]

Here is how you can access the items of the Collection

```
For Each Item In JSON
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item(1)     ' Items reference as an example
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item(2)
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item(3)
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item(4)
    Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item(5)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

I would write a function to convert the JSON data into an Array

```
Public Sub exceljson()
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://api.bitfinex.com/v2/candles/trade:5m:tEOSUSD/hist?start=1535760000000&end=1538265600000&sort=1", False
    http.Send

    Dim results As Variant
    results = BitfinexTextToArray(http.responseText)

    Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2)).Value = results

    MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub

Function BitfinexTextToArray(responseText As String) As Variant
    Dim item As Variant, JSON As Object
    Dim MaxColumns As Long

    Set JSON = ParseJson(responseText)

    For Each item In JSON
        If item.Count > MaxColumns Then MaxColumns = item.Count
    Next

    Dim results As Variant
    ReDim results(1 To JSON.Count, 1 To MaxColumns)

    Dim c As Long, r As Long
    For Each item In JSON
        r = r + 1

        For c = 1 To item.Count
            results(r, c) = item(c)
        Next
    Next

    BitfinexTextToArray = results
End Function
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! The function you provided to convert the JSON data into an Array also worked fine. Good job TinMan