# Receiving a JSON object, are the "wrapping" quare brackets necessary?

Tags: json, vba

I experiment with retrieving JSON objects via my custom scripts and I noticed it works when the object is in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
```

but some apps deliver the object without the outer square brackets, as in:

```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
```

This one does not work.
I am not that familiar witj JSON so unsure which one is correct or hiw thi is called/used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [] indicates a collection. You can For Each over  (with Item as Object i.e. For Each Item in Collection) this or index into it

e.g. json(1) will give first dictionary item in collection

The {} indicates a dictionary which you can For Each over the keys of (with Key as Variant) or access individual items by dict(key)

You may need branched logic using a test for `TypeName(json...)` for example to determine which parent object you are working with.

For info see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494208/6241235).

Comment: Thanks, is not necessary for collection to be used here, why the second example does not use it? It does have a lot of items

Comment: perhaps the second is entirely dictionaries