# 64 bit Excel VBA to call a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, 32bit-64bit, msscriptcontrol

I need to use a VBA ScriptControl object to call a JavaScript function , but it gave me a "Class Not Registered" error. 
I have added Microsoft Script Control 1.0 from Tools->References
I need to call JavaScript to get a JSON object from this [Rest API](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=JPY&apikey=demo) to calculate values in an Excel Macro.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725882/getting-scriptcontrol-to-work-with-excel-2010-x64) told me that ScriptControl is  for use  in 32 bit only. I am using 64 bit Excel. 
I also tried using the method mentioned in this [link](https://tablacus.github.io/scriptcontrol_en.html) but it didn't work since VBA doesn't recognise the ActiveXObject

My Excel VBA code to call a simple JS function:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim jsObj As MSScriptControl.ScriptControl, result As Integer
    Set jsObj = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
    jsObj.Language = "JScript"
    With jsObj
        .AddCode ("function prod1(a,b){return a*b;}")
        result = .Run("prod1", 2, 3)
    End With
    MsgBox result
End Sub
```

I am getting a class not registered error for the line Set jsObj = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
Is there an alternate way to call a JavaScript function from VBA? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use XMLHTTP to call that API?  Doesn't seem like you need a scriptcontrol for this.

Comment: XMLHTTP can be used when the API returns values as XML. This API returns it in JSON

Comment: There is no problem fetching JSON using xmlHTTP - there are plenty of existing questions here on SO which cover that (and parsing the response)  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a ScriptControl object: you can use XMLHTTP and VBA-JSON.

For example:

```vb
Public Sub Tester()

    'Import the "JsonConverter.bas" file from 
    '     https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
    'and add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library
    Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer, o As Object, k

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?" & _
          "function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD" & _
          "&to_currency=JPY&apikey=demo", False

    http.Send

    Debug.Print http.responseText
    Debug.Print "-----------------------------------"

    Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)

    Set o = JSON("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")
    For Each k In o.keys
        Debug.Print k, o(k)
    Next k

End Sub
```