# How to call a JavaScript function from a VBA Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, vba

I want to pass paramaters from VBA to a JavaScript function and then return the result back to the VBA script.
At first my JavaScript Function could look like this:

```
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  return p1 * p2;   
}
```

My question is, if there is any command in VBA to solve this problem.

For the final setup, I want to use Node.js with Selenium to get some Information and send it back to VBA.

I know there are a lot of threads with similar question but I just dont get smart out of them.
Many people use ["execScript method"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741364(v=vs.85)).
Can this be applied to my problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Where* is the JS function? - in a string/file, or in a webbrowser control ...

Comment: The function is in a file.

Comment: Assuming Windows you can use an instance of the `ScriptControl` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166109/64-bit-excel-vba-to-call-a-javascript-function/62166671#62166671

Comment: ...and read the file content using (eg) built-in file functions or maybe Scrripting.FileSystemObject