# Parse API response with JsonConverter: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, coinbase-api

I'm trying to write Excel VBA code that calls an API to fetch data, massage the data, then output the cleaned data over a range of cells in the spreadsheet.

I run into an error while trying to parse the API response with JsonConverter.
I followed the instructions at https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON to install VBA-JSON, and imported JsonConverter.bas into my script, and added the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime".
I installed Tablacus as a 64-bit ScriptControl.

Here's the beginning of the code, and where it hits the error:

```vb
Function IsValidJson(jsonString As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "^[\s\S]*\{[\s\S]*\}[\s\S]*$"
    IsValidJson = regex.Test(jsonString)
End Function

Sub RefreshData()
    Dim url As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim json As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim trading_pairs() As String
    Dim trading_pairs_eth() As String
    Dim trading_pairs_usd() As String
    Dim final_pairs() As String
    Dim final_prices() As Double
    Dim final_volumes() As Double
    Dim pair As String
    Dim volume As Double
    Dim price As Double
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim JsonConverter As Object
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set JsonConverter = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    JsonConverter.Language = "JScript"
    JsonConverter.AddCode "function parseJson(jsonString) { return JSON.parse(jsonString); }"
    
    ' Fetch all trading pairs with BTC as the quote currency
    url = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book"
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send
    If IsValidJson(http.responseText) Then
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)  ' <- error happens here
        ReDim trading_pairs(json("bids").Count - 1)
        For i = 0 To json("bids").Count - 1
            trading_pairs(i) = json("bids")(i)("price")
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON string"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This is part of the whole script, it's quite long.

The line `Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)` is where it is throwing error 438.

I have a IsValidJson function validating the "http.responseText", before attempting to parse it with JsonConverter.
It passes the validation check, but still throws error 438 when trying to parse.

Code originally generated by ChatGPT.

Comment: The missing object is probably `JsonConverter`.

Comment: @CherryDT Yeah, even ChatGPT agreed that it made a mistake there, so we corrected that part of the code and declared "JsonConverter" as an object, but now it throws this error:  "Run-time error '-2147221164 (80040154)': Class not registered" at a new line we inserted, "Set JsonConverter = CreateObject("ScriptControl")".  From what I can tell, is there a JSON "class" that needs to be installed or registered somehow?

Comment: You should include the code of `JsonConverter` from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: Hi @taller, thanks for the tip.  I have followed the Installation instructions for VBA-JSON, but it still throws the same error at the same line of the code.  I feel like I must be missing a critical step somewhere, but I can find no indication of what that may be.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725882/getting-scriptcontrol-to-work-with-excel-2010-x64

Comment: Please learn the sample code and Tutorial Video first. It's helpful to understand how to use JsonConverter. You don't need to have `Set JsonConverter = CreateObject(...)`.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, thanks for that.  Installing Tablacus resolved the issue with Scriptcontrol.  But now I'm getting error 438 when trying to parse the http.responseText.  I added a function to validate the response, ensuring it is a valid JSON string, but this didn't help, and I still get error 438.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON-Converter you linked isn't a class that needs to be instantiated. The code that you display looks like a mixture of (at least) two different things.

The code you need to use is rather simple.

```
Sub RefreshData()
    Const url = "https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/book"

    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    ' Fetch all trading pairs with BTC as the quote currency
    http.Open "GET", url, False
    http.send

    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
    (now your work starts)
End Sub
```

The call `JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)` is the call to the function `ParseJson` of the module `JsonConverter`, not an object. You can omit the module name and simply write `Set json = ParseJson(http.responseText)` - that's exactly the same.

Therefore you need to delete the definition of the variable `JsonConverter`
else the compiler will assume that you want to call a method `ParseJSon` of that object and therefore you will get the 438 error.

I have no clue why you or ChatGPT want to create a `ScriptControl` object, remove that line and the assingments to `Language` and `AddCode` also.

I am also not sure if the function `IsValidJson` is doing it's job, I have removed the call to it. The ParseJSon function will raise an error (10001) if the JSON is not valid.

---

Once this works, you need to walk thru the parsed JSon, and your code will raise the next errors soon. Just some hints:

I had a quick look to `http.responseText`, for me it looked like this:

```
{"bids":[["36575.59","0.51069628",3]],
 "asks":[["36575.6","0.0266337",2]],
 "sequence":68520027803,
 "auction_mode":false,
 "auction":null,
 "time":"2023-11-18T22:04:21.019956Z"}
```

After the call to `ParseJSon`, you have a dictionary as result in variable `json` (check the content with the debugger). The element `bids` is an array with 1 element, and this element itself is an array with 3 elements (3 numbers). The JSonConverter converts an array to a `Collection`. Collections in VBA are 1-based, not 0-based. To get an idea:

```
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText) 
    Debug.Print http.responseText
    Dim bids As Collection, bidvalues As Collection
    Set bids = json("bids")
    ' You now have a collection with one element.
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To bids.Count
        Set bidvalues = bids(i)
        For j = 1 To bidvalues.Count
            Debug.Print i, j, bidvalues(j)
        Next j
    Next i
```

Comment: Okay, ChatGPT clearly did not generate the right code for what I'm trying to do, and also appears to have not even made the right API call (I guess that's what I get for trying to use AI to help with a much-more-complex-than-I-realized coding job).  I can't really summarize what I'm trying to actually do here, because StackOverflow's character limit for comments is too small.  Can you suggest where I can turn, to help me get this macro written properly?