# Why do I get a VBA error running scriptcontrol on excel 64bit?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, msscriptcontrol

I am not tech savy at all but use a workbook created by an old employee. I am getting errors while running a excel VBA script control macro. Colleagues who are still on 32bit done face this issue, but myself who uses 64bit gets an error.

```
Private ScriptEngine As scriptControl

Public Sub InitScriptEngine()
    Set ScriptEngine = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        ScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
        ScriptEngine.Reset
```

The debugger stops at the

```
 Set ScriptEngine = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

I have read elsewhere that Script control will not work on 64 bit is that true?

Comment: Have you seen this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9725882/getting-scriptcontrol-to-work-with-excel-2010-x64)?

Comment: "getting errors" - always helps to be specific about the exact error(s) you're getting.