# VBA array length (not ubound or onerror!)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Sorry to ask such a basic question but this is driving me mad...

What function in VBA returns the number of elements in an array... i.e when the array is empty it will return 0?

I cant do this with UBound because it throws an error when called on an empty array and i cant believe the way to do this by using OnError to first determine if its empty or not... as is suggested on forums! array.Length complains about a bad qualifier or something.

I really need to do this:

```
dim termAry() as String
populate termAry
...

private sub populate(terms() as String)
   redim preserve terms(terms.Length) ' Redim takes ubound for array size
   terms(ubound(terms)) = "something really annoying"
end sub
```

P.S any good links to a concise set of VBA language and function reference would be most useful... MSDN seems really obscure!!!

Comment: what are you trying to do? you need a source for your array - where does it come from

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097021/vba-handle-empty-array-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206324/how-to-check-for-empty-array-in-vba-macro

Comment: all you need to handle this its to say `if ubound(arr) > 1 then ...`, for initialization use `redim arr(MAX)`

Comment: Does the concept of an empty array not exist in VB?

Comment: mehow, ubound throws an exception if array has no elements, what would be nice is a Length(array) function that returns a value between between 0 and Ubound(array)+1.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559804/vba-checking-for-empty-array

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this is to use `On Error` and handle the `Subscript Out of Range` error that will be raised if the array (or the dimension of the array you're interested in) isn't initialized.

E.g.

```
Public Function IsInitialized(arr() As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim nUbound As Long
    nUbound = UBound(arr)
    IsInitialized = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Exit Function
End Function

Dim a() As String
Dim b(0 To 10) As String

IsInitialized(a) ' returns False
IsInitialized(b) ' returns True
```

You can generalized this to test how many dimensions there are in an array, e.g.

```
Public Function HasAtLeastNDimensions(arr() As String, NoDimensions As Long) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim nUbound As Long
    nUbound = UBound(arr, NoDimensions)
    HasAtLeastNDimensions = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Exit Function
End Function

Dim a() As String
Dim b(0 To 10) As String
Dim c(0 To 10, 0 To 5) As String

HasAtLeastNDimensions(a, 1) ' False: a is not initialized
HasAtLeastNDimensions(b, 1) ' True: b has 1 dimension
HasAtLeastNDimensions(b, 2) ' False: b has only 1 dimension
HasAtLeastNDimensions(c, 2) ' True: c has 2 dimensions
```

**UPDATE**

In response to comment:

> am i right in thinking that the function cannot be easily generalised to operate on any array type

It can be easily generalized by making the parameter a Variant, and checking it is an array in the body of the function using the `IsArray` function:

```
Public Function HasAtLeastNDimensions(arr As Variant, NoDimensions As Long) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim nUbound As Long
    If Not IsArray(arr) Then Exit Function
    nUbound = UBound(arr, NoDimensions)
    HasAtLeastNDimensions = True
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: That works fine for string arrays, am i right in thinking that the function cannot be easily generalised to operate on any array type... it seems a deep copy is required with element wise type casting?