# Checking the size of an empty array

Tags: vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine if an array is initialized in VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183353/how-do-i-determine-if-an-array-is-initialized-in-vb6)

I declare an array initially as empty:

```
Dim ArrayVar() as Variant


'May add some data, may not
if something then 
    Redim Preserve ArrayVar(ubound(ArrayVar,1)+1)
    ArrayVar(ubound(ArrayVar,1)) = "something"
end if


'Always check size of array
if ubound(ArrayVar,1) > x
```

the problem is sometimes when I reach checking the size, nothing has been added- the array is empty and I get a run-time error. I did try declaring the array with `Dim ArrayVar(0) as Variant` but then the redim statement wouldnt compile.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: this will answer yoru q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206324/how-to-check-for-empty-array-in-vba-macro

Comment: Nope, said "subscript out of range"

Comment: also this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559804/vba-checking-for-empty-array?rq=1

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов No difference in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IsEmpty() function.

Please try the following code:

```
Dim ArrayVar() As Variant

Sub x()
If IsEmpty(arrvar) Then
    ReDim ArrayVar(0)
Else
    ReDim Preserve ArrayVar(UBound(ArrayVar, 1) + 1)
    ArrayVar(UBound(ArrayVar, 1)) = "something"
End If

MsgBox UBound(ArrayVar, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: `IsEmpty` cannot be used to determine if an array is empty (it will always return `False`). This code works only because the array variable is `ArrayVar`, but the code checks `arrvar` for emptiness. If you fix it and correctly call `IsEmpty(ArrayVar)`, you will have runtime error 9 on trying to get `UBound(ArrayVar, 1)` of the empty array.