# How to search for string in an array

Tags: arrays, vba

Is there an easy (one-liner) to search for a string within an array in VBA?  Or will I need to loop through each element and compare it with the target string?

EDIT:
It is a one-dimensional array.  I only need to know *IF* a string is somewhere in the array.

IE:

```
names(JOHN, BOB, JAMES, PHLLIP)
```

How do I find out if "JOHN" is in the array, it needs to be minimal as it will be repeated around 5000 times and I don't want the function to slow the overall process down.

Comment: Do you just want to know if the string is one of the array elements? Or do you want the index of the matching element?

Answer (score 82):

If you want to know if the string is found in the array at all, try this function:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

As [SeanC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952084/190829) points out, this must be a 1-D array.

**Example:**

```
Sub Test()
  Dim arr As Variant
  arr = Split("abc,def,ghi,jkl", ",")
  Debug.Print IsInArray("ghi", arr)
End Sub
```

(Below code updated based on comment from [HansUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-ms-access-vba-array#comment14354047_10952705))

If you want the index of the matching element in the array, try this:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      IsInArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

This also assumes a 1-D array. Keep in mind LBound and UBound are zero-based so an index of 2 means the third element, not the second.

**Example:**

```
Sub Test()
  Dim arr As Variant
  arr = Split("abc,def,ghi,jkl", ",")
  Debug.Print (IsInArray("ghi", arr) > -1)
End Sub
```

**If you have a specific example in mind, please update your question with it, otherwise example code might not apply to your situation.**

Comment: The second version of `IsInArray` returns 0 if `stringToBeFound` is not found in `arr`.

Comment: @HansUp I know, but what do you suggest?

Comment: I would assign a value, such as -1, which couldn't be returned by `UBound()` of a non-empty array. `Dim lngReturn As Long; lngReturn = -1` If `stringToBeFound` is found: `lngReturn = i`  Finally, `IsInArray = lngReturn`

Comment: @HansUp You're right, but I could simply remove that whole section of code as the OP doesn't want it anyway :)

Comment: Note that you will get an error if the initial array is empty. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206324/how-to-check-for-empty-array-in-vba-macro/206526#206526

Comment: @Remou Checking for empty arrays should be encapsulated into a different function.

Comment: @JimmyPena fyi posted a late reply to your post contradicting to some extent the need for 1-dim arrays only :-)

Comment: Note that this solution suffers from an important unexpected behavior.  If the string you are searching partially matches any entry, it will be considered a match. Example if you search `g` in the example in `Test()` will return True.  If you need exact match you will need to loop and compare (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa164525(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Moreover, this function is case insensitive (it will match "john" against "JOHNSON"). So I agree with @mellamokb This function does not what the OP requested.

Answer (score 33):

Another option would be use a dictionary instead of an array:

```
Dim oNames As Object
Set oNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'You could if need be create this automatically from an existing Array
'The 1 is just a dummy value, we just want the names as keys
oNames.Add "JOHN", 1
oNames.Add "BOB", 1
oNames.Add "JAMES", 1
oNames.Add "PHILIP", 1
```

As this would then get you a one-liner of

```
oNames.Exists("JOHN")
```

The advantage a dictionary provides is exact matching over partial matching from `Filter`. Say if you have the original list of names in an Array, but were looking for "JO" or "PHIL" who were actually two new people in addition to the four we started with. In this case, `Filter(oNAMES, "JO")` will match "JOHN" which *may* not be desired. With a dictionary, it won't.

Comment: perfect for my purpose!

Answer (score 14):

Another option that enforces exact matching (i.e. no partial matching) would be:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function
```

You can read more about the Match method and its arguments at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 7):

there is a function that will return an **array** of all the strings found.

`Filter(sourcearray, match[, include[, compare]])`
The sourcearray has to be 1 dimensional
The function will return all strings in the array that have the `match` string in them

Answer (score 7):

Here's another answer. It works fast, reliably (see atomicules' answer) and has compact calling code:

```
' Returns true if item is in the array; false otherwise.
Function IsInArray(ar, item$) As Boolean
    Dim delimiter$, list$

    ' Chr(7) is the ASCII 'Bell' Character.
    ' It was chosen for being unlikely to be found in a normal array.
    delimiter = Chr(7)

    ' Create a list string containing all the items in the array separated by the delimiter.
    list = delimiter & Join(ar, delimiter) & delimiter

    IsInArray = InStr(list, delimiter & item & delimiter) > 0
End Function
```

**Sample usage:**

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print "Is 'A' in the list?", IsInArray(Split("A,B", ","), "A")
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the most reliable answer...if user has to find entire match within array...:)

Comment: This answer is not memory efficient nor performant for larger arrays (great than ~100 elements) due to all the `String` concatenation required.

Answer (score 5):

more simple Function whichs works on Apple OS too:

```
Function isInArray(ByVal stringToBeFound As String, ByVal arr As Variant) As Boolean
Dim element
For Each element In arr
    If element = stringToBeFound Then
        isInArray = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next element
End Function
```

Comment: I think you have to do `Dim element` before the For loop (at least, if you have Option Explicit on, which you should.

Answer (score 3):

This is my code, inspired by @atomicules

```
Public Function IsName(name As String) As Boolean
  Dim names As Object
  Set names = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

  names.Add "JOHN"
  names.Add "BOB"
  names.Add "JAMES"
  names.Add "PHLLIP"
  
  IsName = names.Contains(name)
    
End Function
```

And this is usage:

```
If IsName("JOHN") Then ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following without the wrapper function, but it provides a nicer API:

```
Function IsInArray(ByVal findString as String, ByVal arrayToSearch as Variant) as Boolean
  IsInArray = UBound(Filter(arrayToSearch,findString)) >= 0
End Function
```

The `Filter` function has the following signature:

`Filter(sourceArray, stringToMatch, [Include As Boolean = True], [Compare as VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare])`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a list of constants then you can use Select Case as follows:

```
Dim Item$: Item = "A"

Select Case Item
  Case "A", "B", "C"
    ' If 'Item' is in the list then do something.
  Case Else
    ' Otherwise do something else.
End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

**Completing remark to Jimmy Pena's accepted answer**

> *As [SeanC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952084/190829) points out, this **must** be a 1-D array.*

The following example call demonstrates that the `IsInArray()` function cannot be called *only* for *1-dim* arrays,
but *also* for **"flat" 2-dim** arrays:

```
Sub TestIsInArray()
    Const SearchItem As String = "ghi"
    Debug.Print "SearchItem = '" & SearchItem & "'"
    '----
    'a) Test 1-dim array
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = Split("abc,def,ghi,jkl", ",")
    Debug.Print "a) 1-dim array " & vbNewLine & "   " & Join(Arr, "|") & " ~~> " & IsInArray(SearchItem, Arr)
    '----
    
        '//quick tool to create a 2-dim 1-based array
        Dim v As Variant, vals As Variant                                       
        v = Array(Array("abc", "def", "dummy", "jkl", 5), _
                  Array("mno", "pqr", "stu", "ghi", "vwx"))
        v = Application.Index(v, 0, 0)  ' create 2-dim array (2 rows, 5 cols)
    
    'b) Test "flat" 2-dim arrays
    Debug.Print "b) ""flat"" 2-dim arrays "
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        'slice "flat" 2-dim arrays of one row each
        vals = Application.Index(v, i, 0)
        'check for findings
        Debug.Print Format(i, "   0"), Join(vals, "|") & " ~~> " & IsInArray(SearchItem, vals)
    Next i
End Sub
```

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, Arr As Variant) As Boolean
'Site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-an-array/10952705
'Note: needs a "flat" array, not necessarily a 1-dimensioned array
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(Arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

**Results in VB Editor's immediate window**

```
SearchItem = 'ghi'
a) 1-dim array 
   abc|def|ghi|jkl ~~> True
b) "flat" 2-dim arrays 
   1          abc|def|dummy|jkl|5         False
   2          mno|pqr|stu|ghi|vwx         True
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Case` statement might suit some applications more simply:

```
select case var
case "a string", "another string", sVar
  'do something
case else
  'do something else
end select
```