# Check if textbox.text exist in array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox

Here i have my simple code, containt list of arrays and 2 text boxes, when i press button script must check if text form Textbox2 is found in list of array. Can you help me to fix it ?
Thanks !

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim pins() As String = {"dgge", "wada", "caas", "reaa"}
    If TextBox2.Text = pins() Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Succes"
    End If End Sub
```

Comment: `If pins.IndexOf(textBox2.Text) <> -1 Then ... End If` (assuming I remember VB correctly.) p.s. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/298053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use LINQ, you can just do this:

```
If pins.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Success"
End If
```

Otherwise, the easiest option would be to use a `List` instead of an array:

```
Dim pins As New List(Of String)(New String() {"dgge", "wada", "caas", "reaa"})
If pins.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Success"
End If
```

But, if you must use an array, you can use the `IndexOf` method in the `Array` class:

```
If Array.IndexOf(TextBox2.Text) >=0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Success"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Array.IndexOf(pins, TextBox2.Text) <> -1 Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Succes"
End If End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If pins.IndexOf(TextBox2.Text) >= 0 Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Founded"
End If
```

Or if you use `List(Of String)` instead of array:

```
If pins.Contains(TextBox2.Text) Then
    TextBox1.Text = "Founded"
End If
```