# Difference between two 2D arrays in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, multidimensional-array, array-difference

I am trying to get the difference between two arrays in excel VBA.

I found a solution to what I am trying to achieve here: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600286/create-third-array-from-difference-of-two-arrays)

But it seems to work only with 1D arrays.

Here you have a sample of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I have tried to modify the code I found and use Jagged Arrays but it didn't work out.
I got `error 13  type mismatch` on this line: `coll.Add arr1(i, j), arr1(i, j)`

this is how my code looks like now:

```
        Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim arr3 As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long, j As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With
Set coll = New Collection
For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr1, 2) To UBound(arr1, 2)
        coll.Add arr1(i, j), arr1(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
    For j = LBound(arr2, 2) To UBound(arr2, 2)
        On Error Resume Next
        coll.Add arr2(i, j), arr2(i, j)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            coll.Remove arr2(i, j)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
   Next j
Next i

ReDim arr3(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To coll.Count
    arr3(i, 1) = coll(i)
    Debug.Print arr3(i, 1)
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arr3, 1), 1).Value = arr3
End Sub
```

Anyone know how it could be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here we have the solution:

```
Sub test()

Dim arr1 As Variant
Dim arr2 As Variant
Dim arr3 As Variant
Dim coll As Collection
Dim i As Long, j As Long, ii As Long, txt As String, x

With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRowColumnA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arr2 = .Range("A1:C" & LastRowColumnA).Value
End With
Set coll = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    txt = Join(Array(arr1(i, 1), arr1(i, 2), arr1(i, 3)), Chr(2))
    coll.Add txt, txt
Next i

For i = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
    txt = Join(Array(arr2(i, 1), arr2(i, 2), arr2(i, 3)), Chr(2))
    Err.Clear
    coll.Add txt, txt
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then coll.Remove txt
Next i

ReDim arr3(1 To coll.Count, 1 To 3)

For i = 1 To coll.Count
    x = Split(coll(i), Chr(2))
    For ii = 0 To 2
        arr3(i, ii + 1) = x(ii)
    Next
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F1").Resize(UBound(arr3, 1), 3).Value = arr3
End Sub
```