# If value from one sheet matches in another sheet then paste that row in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance, I am trying to match values from sheet1 in column "D" to column A of sheet2 and if any got matched then copy pasting entire row to sheet3 and then delete the entire row from sheet1.

Below code is working fine for matching and deleting:

```
Sub remDup()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("D" & i).Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Columns("A"), 0)) Then .Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

but it doesn't paste's the deleted row in sheet3.

Tried to do something like but no success.

```
Sub remDup()
Dim LR As Long, i As Long, n As Long
With Sheets("sheet1")
    LR = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("D" & i).Value, Sheets("sheet2").Columns("A"), 0)) Then Sheets("sheet3").Row(n) = Rows(i) & .Rows(i).Delete
        n = n + 1
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Please help, and I also have to match it with three columns in sheet 2 (A, B and C) but in this code I have done it ones with column A only and thought that will run the same code thrice by changing the column name.

Is there a way to do it at once.

Thanks Again.

Comment: If your code is working fine for matching and deleting, add `Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(n)` inside your `if` clause. And add an `End if` that is lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. **EDITED.** IsInArray function from [JimmyPenna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190829/jimmypena). Link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/1726522).

```
Sub remDup()
Dim LR As Long, LRSheet2 As Long, i As Long, a As Long
Dim vAllSheet2Values() As Variant

LRSheet2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LR = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
a = 1

For i = 1 To LRSheet2 'Load all values in ColumnA of Sheet2 into an array
    ReDim Preserve vAllSheet2Values(i)
    vAllSheet2Values(i) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
Next i

For i = LR To 1 Step -1
    If IsInArray(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value, vAllSheet2Values) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows(a)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Delete
        a = a + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub

'https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/1726522
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks alot for helping but there is slight thing I didn't explained well it seems. 
By below condition I mean I want to lookup in whole range

If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("D" & i).Value, Sheets("sheet2").Columns("A"), 0))

if I do 

If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value then it would be static row to row match only and if the value exits in some other row then it gets skipped.

Please help

Comment: @ScottCraner Dear Scott,

You helped me once and I wonder if you can help me now here as stuck in a silly issue.

Comment: @SK I know I'm several light years behind ScottCraner, but a feedback to my effort would be nice anyway. Does code helped you?

Comment: Yes it does. Thanks!!

Comment: @SK Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am actually trying to use InStr in place of IsInArray but getting compile error. Can't I do that replacing it if not then how should I do that please help