# VBA if with InStr

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA code with if the i get an error.

I want the code to check if one of the values  ("S925,S936,S926,G") is not on cell 10.

```
Sub checklist()

 Dim x
Dim LineType

NumRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To NumRows

    If LineType = "G" Then
        If Not InStr("S925,S936,S926,G", cellsCells(x, 10).Value) Then
       cells     Cells(x, 52).Interior.Color = rgbCrimson
       cells     Cells(x, 52).Value = "G"


 End If
      End If


    End If

Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11112615/4604845) for a solution to a slightly different question that uses `InStr` to essentially solve the problem in a way that is identical to your approach.

Comment: what kind of error? you only removed part of the loop so your example wouldn't even compile.

Comment: where is your `For x = ...` ? you have only the closing statement `Next x`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add this: 'Sub checklist()
 
 Dim x

    Dim LineType
       
 NumRows = cells(Rows.Count, "j").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 2 To NumRows'

Comment: What the hell happened in that last edit? It doesn't make any sense. Please describe your error if you want help. Check if you have a variable or function called `cells`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't cause an error but it will cause issues with your program so I'll explain it.

`InStr` doesn't return a Boolean but the index of the first occurrence of the search string. If the string isn't found it returns 0.
For example `InStr("12345", "23")` will return 2.
Because everything except 0 is cast as `True`, something like `If Instr(....) Then` will perform as expected.

However if you use `If Not InStr(....) Then` something else can/will happen

```
If Not InStr("12345", "23") Then
    Debug.Print "test evaluated as True!"
End If
```

this prints `test evaluated as True!` even though "23" is contained in "12345". This is not because `InStr` returned `False` though. We can replace the `InStr` expression with 2 to better understand:

```
Debug.Print 2               '2 (duh)
Debug.Print CBool(2)        'True (2 converted to Boolean)
Debug.Print Not 2           '-3
Debug.Print CBool(Not 2)    'True (-2 converted to Boolean)
```

Wy is `Not 2` evaluated as -3? That's because the `2` isn't converted to Boolean before `Not` is applied but the `Not` is applied bit-wise to the `2`, which means every bit is flipped. So 2 (`0010`) becomes `1101` which is -3 because the computer uses the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to express negative numbers. (Actually more bits are used for `Integer` but it works the same.) As -3 is not 0, it will be converted to `True`. Since `Not 0` will also be evaluated as `True` (`0000` will be converted to `1111` which is -1 as two's complement) the expression `Not InStr(...)` will always be evaluated as True.

This bit-wise behavior isn't noticed when working with Booleans because they are represented as `0000` and `1111` internally. This also becomes apparent like this:

```
Debug.Print 1 = True        'False
Debug.Print CBool(1) = True 'True
Debug.Print -1 = True       'True
Debug.Print CBool(-1) = True'True
Debug.Print CInt(True)      '-1 (True converted to Integer)
```

As you can see here, the `True` is converted to an Integer rather than the Integer being converted to a Boolean for the `=` comparison.

---

Long explanation, **short fix**: Use `If InStr(...) > 0 Then` instead of `If InStr(...) Then` and `If InStr(...) = 0 Then` instead of `If Not InStr(...) Then`.

---

PS: This can also cause confusing behavior if you combine two `InStr` tests with `And` because `And` will be applied bitwise as well.