# Automatically Create Folders By Extension

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I have a code that is working and is organizing files by extension. However, it works in only one folder at this time.

Suppose in a parent folder I have 500 subfolders and in each subfolder, there are files with different extensions (e.g. XML, PDF, Word, text, etc). Currently, I need to select each subfolder one at a time and move files into folders by extension via the below code.

However, I need a method where when I select a parent directory, the code should read each subfolder and in each subfolder create folders by extension and move the files to it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OrganiseFilesbyFileType()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim Folderpath As String
    Dim Fle As Scripting.File
    
    Dim FoldpathPrompt As FileDialog
    Set FoldpathPrompt = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With FoldpathPrompt
        .Title = "Select the folder you want to organise files in"
        If .Show = -1 Then Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    If Folderpath <> "" Then
        
        Dim ParentPath As String
        ParentPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(Folderpath)
            
        Dim FolderName As String
        FolderName = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Name
        
        Dim NewFoldPath As String
        NewFoldPath = ParentPath & "\" & FolderName & " - Organized" & "\"
        
        Dim TheFolder As Scripting.Folder
        Set TheFolder = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath)
        
        fso.CreateFolder NewFoldPath
        
        For Each Fle In TheFolder.Files
            If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFoldPath & Fle.Type) Then
                fso.CreateFolder (NewFoldPath & Fle.Type)
            End If
            Fle.Copy NewFoldPath & Fle.Type & "\" & Fle.Name
        Next Fle
        
        TheFolder.Delete
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't ` Fle.Copy` be ` Fle.Move` ?  I believe that, `TheFolder.Delete` will try and delete the folder and all it's contents but will fail when a sub-folder has files in it.   Deleting the folder doesn't seem to be part of the specifications.  It also a little weird that you are targeting the parent folder and not the one chosen by the folder dialog.

Comment: And what is not working on your code? Where are you stuck? What error do you get?

Comment: Compile Error (Variable not defined) this is the error it gives

Comment: @SalmanShafi and in which line do get this error?

Comment: NewFoldpath = ParentPath & "\" & FolderName & " - Organized" & "\"

Comment: It gives error in above-mentioned line

Comment: `NewFoldpath` is not defined.  I recommend watching: [Master VBA Debugging in 20 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um2JwZfwoFI)

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru I have fixed the code by defining Newfoldpath however can you please now see the question again. thanks

Comment: Please have a look on the [SubFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/folders-collection) method of the fileSystem-Object

Comment: This is not a real fix, as the respective warning was not a real error... When I connected to your computer in order to understand what's happening with your last question which worked on my laptop and not on yours, I made some changes  in VBE `Options`. Now `Option Explcit` is automatically added on top of any newly created module. It does not let you working with not declared variables! In this specific case the code could run without that code line, but it is extremely good to have this option. I mean, having `Dim count_0` and by mistake using `count_o` the code shows you the mistake...

Comment: Than how can i make extension wise folders in every folder automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Organize Files By File Type

**Main**

```vb
Sub OrganizeFilesByFileType()

    Const iFolderPath As String = "E:\2022" ' adjust!!!
    Const Title As String = "Select the folder you want to organize files in"
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = PickFolder(iFolderPath, Title)
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FolderPaths As Collection
    Set FolderPaths = CollSubfolderPaths(FolderPath)
    
    MoveFilesToTypeFolders FolderPaths

End Sub
```

**Folder Picker**

```vb
Function PickFolder( _
    Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _
    Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK", _
    Optional ByVal ShowCancelMessage As Boolean = True) _
As String
    
    Dim FolderPath As String, IsFolderPicked As Boolean
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName
        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then
            FolderPath = InitialFolderPath
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            .InitialFileName = FolderPath
        End If
        If .Show Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            IsFolderPicked = True
        End If
    End With
    
    If IsFolderPicked Then PickFolder = FolderPath: Exit Function
        
    If ShowCancelMessage Then
        MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, "Pick Folder"
    End If

End Function
```

**Subfolder Paths To Collection**

```vb
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of a folder ('FolderPath')
'               and all of its subfolders in a collection.
' Remarks:      Check it only against 'Nothing' (its count cannot be 0).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CollSubfolderPaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _
As Collection
    Const ProcName As String = "CollSubFolderPaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim collPaths As Collection: Set collPaths = New Collection
    
    Dim collQueue As Collection: Set collQueue = New Collection
    collQueue.Add fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object

    Do Until collQueue.Count = 0
        Set fsoFolder = collQueue(1)
        collQueue.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
        collPaths.Add fsoFolder.Path
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
            collQueue.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
        Next fsoSubfolder
    Loop
      
    If Not IncludeFolderPath Then
        If collPaths.Count = 1 Then Exit Function
        collPaths.Remove 1
    End If
    
    Set CollSubfolderPaths = collPaths

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

**Move Files To Type Folders**

```vb
Sub MoveFilesToTypeFolders( _
        ByVal FolderPaths As Collection, _
        Optional ByVal ShowMessage As Boolean = True)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Files To Type Folders"
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Keys: Type Folder Paths (New), Items: True or False i.e. exists or not
    Dim foDict As Object: Set foDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    foDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    ' Keys: File Paths (Old), Items: Type File Paths (New)
    Dim fiDict As Object: Set fiDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fiDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Item, fsoFolder As Object, fsoFile As Object
    Dim FolderName As String, FileType As String, TypePath As String
    
    For Each Item In FolderPaths
        Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(Item)
        FolderName = fsoFolder.Name
        For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
            FileType = fsoFile.Type
            If StrComp(FolderName, FileType, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                TypePath = fso.BuildPath(Item, FileType)
                If Not foDict.Exists(TypePath) Then
                    foDict(TypePath) = fso.FolderExists(TypePath)
                End If
                fiDict(fsoFile.Path) = fso.BuildPath(TypePath, fsoFile.Name)
            'Else ' the file is already in its type folder; do nothing
            End If
        Next fsoFile
    Next Item
    
    ' Create the folders.
    For Each Item In foDict.Keys
        If Not foDict(Item) Then fso.CreateFolder Item
    Next Item

    ' Move the files.
    For Each Item In fiDict.Keys
        fso.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)
    Next Item

    If ShowMessage Then
        If fiDict.Count > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Files moved to type folders.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            MsgBox "No files found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Sir @VBasic2008  It gives error when i run all 4 subs you just have provided. Error (Run Time Error "70"     Permission Denied)  And the line where it gives error is in the last sub fso.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)

Comment: However it still creates the new folders in subfolders but due to error not moving the files in them. I request if you could please check

Comment: I will also really be thankful if you put a (file replace) option in it where if a file is already available in Subfolders or in the organized folders, and if moved the same file again it can kill previous file and replace it with the latest file. Bundle of thanks

Comment: I can't help you. You need to figure this out. `Permission Denied` usually occurs when a file is open. Check that no file is open in Excel or another application and try again. You can use the line `Debug.Print Item, fiDict(Item)` right before `fso.MoveFile...` to identify the file.

Comment: let me check again

Comment: Dear @VBasic2008 yes it is working perfectly, amazingly.... Actually the excel sheet was in the same folder and opened in which the macro is saved, however, i have move the sheet in some other Drive and it worked. Thanks a lot. Its working perfectly

Comment: Dear Sir @VBasic2008 currently all functions are working properly. is it possible if you could please help in suggesting where if a file in subfolder or folders within subfolders are already available and if the same file was moved it should replace the file with the latest file (i.e. previous file should either be killed or deleted) and new file will be saved). currently it gives msg as "File Already exist).  Rest everything is perfect. Thank you

Comment: Dear @Vbasic2008 can you please this question please, since you have provided this wonderful solution, i believe it would be easier for you, i will remain thankful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75082921/to-replace-the-new-file-with-the-old-while-organizing-the-files-into-folders

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function, example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub OrganiseFilesbyFileType()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Dim Folderpath As String
    Dim Fle As Scripting.File
    
    Dim FoldpathPrompt As FileDialog
    Set FoldpathPrompt = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With FoldpathPrompt
        .Title = "Select the folder you want to organise files in"
        If .Show = -1 Then Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    If Folderpath <> "" Then
        
        Dim ParentPath As String
        ParentPath = fso.GetParentFolderName(Folderpath)
            
        Dim FolderName As String
        FolderName = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Name
        
        Dim NewFoldPath As String
        NewFoldPath = ParentPath & "\" & FolderName & " - Organized" & "\"
        
        Dim TheFolder As Scripting.Folder
        Set TheFolder = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath)
        
        fso.CreateFolder NewFoldPath
        
        Call OrganiseFilesbyFileTypeSubfolders(fso, NewFoldPath, TheFolder)
        
        TheFolder.Delete
    
    End If

End Sub

Sub OrganiseFilesbyFileTypeSubfolders(ByVal pFso As Object, ByVal pNewFoldPath As String, ByVal pFsoSubfolder As Object)
    Dim Fle As Object
    Dim NewFoldPath As String
    
    For Each Fle In pFsoSubfolder.Files
        If Not pFso.FolderExists(pNewFoldPath & Fle.Type) Then
            pFso.CreateFolder (pNewFoldPath & Fle.Type)
        End If
        Fle.Copy pNewFoldPath & Fle.Type & "\" & Fle.Name
    Next Fle
    Dim subfolder As Object
    For Each subfolder In pFsoSubfolder.SubFolders
        NewFoldPath = pNewFoldPath & subfolder.Name & "\"
        pFso.CreateFolder NewFoldPath
        Call OrganiseFilesbyFileTypeSubfolders(pFso, NewFoldPath, subfolder)
    Next subfolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @Paulo The current code is deleting the subfolders and organizing the files in parent directory. However, it requires to organize and create folders extension wise within the subfolders. can you please check

Comment: Dear @Paulo this provided code is doing the same function if i select subfolder one by one. Since there are 500 subfolders therefore i would request if that can be possible if i only select Parent Directory and in Parent Directory it can organized the folders within Subfolders. Thanks