# List folder names and count number of files in each folder

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

I found code on YouTube.

1. It counts Excel files.
   How can it read all the extensions in a folder?
2. It counts one directory.
   How can it read the subfolders and count files in them as well?
3. It displays the count answer in a message box.
   How can it display the answer in Column B?

E.g. There are five subfolders and each contains files with different extensions.

The code should read all the subfolders and list the name of folder in Excel and also count and return the answer in front of each folder name.

```vb
Sub CountFiles()
    Dim strDir As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim objFiles As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim lngFileCount As Long
       
    strDir = "E:\2022\"
   
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
    Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(strDir).Files
   
    lngFileCount = objFiles.count
   
    MsgBox lngFileCount     'Total number of files
   
   
    '***************************************************
    'NOTE: Ensure that the following code does not overwrite _
     anything in your workbook.
    'Active worksheet should be a blank worksheet
   
    For Each obj In objFiles
      ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = obj.Name
    Next obj
   
    Set objFiles = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set obj = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Are all 5 subfolders in the same folder (`E:\2022`)? What is the expected result? Describe it in detail or even better, post a screenshot.

Comment: _"Can anyone please edit so that it should read all the extension in folder(s)."_ : well it'd be much, much better if you posted your attempts at it along with what's going wrong

Comment: _"is it possible if it can be edited so it should read the subfolders and count files in them as well."_: yes it is. And you can find dozens (if not hundreds) of example in SO. Have your "trial & error" session and come back with its results

Comment: _"it is possible if it displays the answer in Column B."_: yes, its. Just tweak a little bit the code you already have for writing the file name in column A

Comment: @VBasic2008 yes all subfolders are in one parent folder "E:\2022\

Comment: @user3598756 Thanks for answer. i have mentioned the code i have in my question. I am learning codes and have no such experience :( but i love VBA

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have added an example of folders in a screenshot, please note there will be more than 500 subfolders in one main folder.  Writing 5 folders is just an example

Comment: I meant for you to post a screenshot of the results in the worksheet. The code I posted, writes the folder names to column B and the files count to column A (`.Offset(, -1)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### List Subfolders

```
Sub ListSubfolders()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const FolderPath As String = "E:\2022\"
     
    ' Reference the folder.
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The folder """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    ' Reference the first cell.
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim fCell As Range
    Set fCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    ' Write the folder properties.
    ' If you don't want this, then out-comment it but also copy the line
    ' 'Set fCell = fCell.Offset(1)' to the bottom of the loop.  
    fCell.Value = fsoFolder.Name
    fCell.Offset(, -1).Value = fsoFolder.Files.Count
    
    ' Write the subfolders' properties.
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object
    For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.Subfolders
        Set fCell = fCell.Offset(1)
        fCell.Value = fsoSubfolder.Name
        fCell.Offset(, -1).Value = fsoSubfolder.Files.Count
    Next fsoSubfolder
   
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Folders listed.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: This is working fine, it is possible if Name of the files could be in Column A and Count in Column B. I

Comment: Yes, make the following changes: replace `"B"` with `"A"`; replace both occurrences of `-1` with `1`.

Comment: Dear Sir @VBasic2008 since you have provided amazing code and solution for above-mentioned query, can you please also look into the query which is still not resolved. i beleive you can help me in this   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624324/to-make-automatic-folders-extension-wise

Comment: Dear @VBasic2008 i request for some more changes. Provided above-code works perfectly fine. however, i noticed that within each subfolders there are 2 to 3 more folders and each folder has extension wise files. this means in each subfolders there are (Winzip) (Word) and (XML) etc. folders too. Is there any possibility where the code can also read these folders which are in each subfolder. currently it only reads Sub folders only and does not read more. If it requires to raise separate question i will do it. Thanks

Comment: The 1st question in your (my) 1st comment was about this issue. Nevermind. I'll look into both issues.

Comment: i am sorry i have noticed this late, however for details i have raised this as a separate question which you can find it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992880/to-count-number-of-files-in-each-of-folder-and-subfolder

Comment: i will be thankful to you if there is any solution

Comment: Dear @VBasic2008  one of the stackoverflow member has provided a solution for the current issue, however i have just last task left which is still not resolved,. i wish if you could help in this regard. please see the query at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74624324/automatically-create-folders-by-extension