# To Count number of files in each of folder and subfolder

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

Yesterday I have been provided with a wonderful code by @VBasic2008 that is working perfectly fine.

In a parent directory if there are 500 subfolders, the code lists down the names of each subfolder in excel sheet and also count number of files available in each subfolder and return the value in excel sheet as well and by this way I am able to verify which folders have how many files in it.

However, I request I need to add one more step in it which is difficult for me.

I have noticed that within each subfolders there are 3 to 4 more folders and the files are organized in these folders extension wise (see below screenshot). means in each subfolders there are (Zip) (Word) (PDF) (XML) etc.

[image: Folders within Subfolders]

Is there any possibility where the code can also read these folders which are in each subfolder and can return the answer like mentioned below

[image: Result can be like this]

If the result is not possible the way i suggested above than any format will be okay. but the only requirement is that it can read the folder properties within each subfolder and can return result.

Sub ListSubfolders()

```
' Define constants.
Const FolderPath As String = "E:\2022\"
 
' Reference the folder.
Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "The folder """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

' Reference the first cell.
If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim fCell As Range
Set fCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

' Write the folder properties.
' If you don't want this, then out-comment it but also copy the line
' 'Set fCell = fCell.Offset(1)' to the bottom of the loop.
fCell.Value = fsoFolder.Name
fCell.Offset(, 1).Value = fsoFolder.Files.Count

' Write the subfolders' properties.
Dim fsoSubfolder As Object
For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
    Set fCell = fCell.Offset(1)
    fCell.Value = fsoSubfolder.Name
    fCell.Offset(, 1).Value = fsoSubfolder.Files.Count
Next fsoSubfolder
 
End Sub
```

This will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to understand your question... Do you want to count all PDF/XML/DOC/etc in *all* subfolders, i.e. recursive count?

Comment: @Gowire yes it requires to count all the files which are in subfolders and/or if there are more folders in each subfolders too

Comment: "can return the answer like mentioned below" is not enough to understand what you globally need. Do you expect us to read the code and understand where *what you show to be inserted/added*? Should this part be returned in a different sheet? **Don't you need the subfolder name where all those exist**, at least? Then, your table starts with "File Name" column. Should we understand that in the mentioned subfolders will only exist files named as "File Name", but with different extensions? Should the code check that? Your code returns only folder and subfolders data related to number of files...

Comment: I can understand/deduce that there are files in folder and in its subfolders. The above code does  not return any such a file name. If there are dedicated subfolders in main subfolders, how files also exist in the main subfolder? Something with different extension than the dedicated ones?

Comment: @FaneDuru There are 500 Folders in a parent directory and in each of the folder there are more folders according to file extension (e.g. Word files are saved in Word folder, XML files are saved in XML folders) therefore it requires to read those 500 folders and also folders within folder

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes names of the folders within each subfolders are also important because only then i can different which folder has how many files.  Some examples of Folders within each subfolders are (Microsoft Word Document) (Text Document) (XML File)

Comment: I am afraid you did not clarify any of my clarification questions in a way to understand what is to be done... I did not ask if "folders are important". I wanted to know **where in your shown table to appear their name**. Should I understand that instead of "File Name" you want meaning "Subfolder name"? If not, where the subfolder name to be written? Taking in consideration that in such a folder many files may exist. Then, I asked about *files existence in the subfolders, too, not only in their subfolders* and you did not say anything. Then the name of files except extension must be the same?

Comment: If not the same, how to be different numbers in involved subfolders?

Comment: @FaneDuru for now i have limited access. I will reply tomorrow. Thank u

Comment: @FaneDuru The name of Subfolders should be appeared in Column A and the file properties in Column B. Now if There are more folders within Sub folders Their names can be appeared in Column A (so that i can identify that in a subfolder there are more folders) and Then the result of number of files can be appeared in Column C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see the images that you put in your question, but you can do a recursive function to count all files in subfolders

In example bellow, in first cell of each subdirectory is put a number indicating the sublevel, then in column of that sublevel is the name and the total of files is in the next column.

```
Sub CountAllFiles()    
Const FolderPath As String = "E:\2022\"
 
' Reference the folder.
Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
    MsgBox "The folder """ & FolderPath & """ doesn't exist.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
Dim fsoFolder As Object: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)

' Reference the first cell.
If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbooks open
If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim fCell As Range
Set fCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

' Write the folder properties.
' If you don't want this, then out-comment it but also copy the line
' 'Set fCell = fCell.Offset(1)' to the bottom of the loop.
fCell.Value = fsoFolder.Name
fCell.Offset(, 1).Value = fsoFolder.Files.Count

' Write the subfolders' properties.
Dim fsoSubfolder As Object
For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
    Set fCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    fCell.Value = fsoSubfolder.Name
    fCell.Offset(, 1).Value = fsoSubfolder.Files.Count
    Call countFiles(ws, fCell.Row, fsoSubfolder)
Next fsoSubfolder
End Sub    

Sub countFiles(ByVal ws As Worksheet, ByVal pRow As Integer, ByVal pFsoSubfolder As Object)
Dim col As Integer
Dim totCol As Integer
Dim foundName As Boolean

For Each fsoSubfolder In pFsoSubfolder.SubFolders
    ' find subfolder name in columns
    totCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    foundName = False
    For col = 3 To totCol
        If ws.Cells(1, col).Value = fsoSubfolder.Name Then
            foundName = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col
    If Not foundName Then
        ws.Cells(1, col).Value = "'" & fsoSubfolder.Name
    End If
    ws.Cells(pRow, col).Value = "'" & fsoSubfolder.Files.Count
    Call countFiles(ws, pRow, fsoSubfolder)
Next fsoSubfolder
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes you have understood the concept and the results are perfectly correct. currently it is reading the Subfolders and also this is reading the folders in each subfolders too and displaying the counts as well

Comment: Let me check in detail and i will revert

Comment: The results are correct and it is fulfilling the requirement, i just request for one change, Currently for each extension wise folder it gives the result in separate rows ,e.g. in Row 6 it shows result of XML files then in row 7 it shows result of word files, etc. Is it possible that rather than returning result in rows for each extension folder if i could write the headings in columns and result should display in them always, this way i can have a better report

Comment: e.g. In column A, Row 2 It should display file name, in Column B, Row 2 it should display the count of XML files, It column C, Row 2 it displays the count of Word files. If there are no files for that extension it can display 0 or -

Comment: currently i have 6 formats which includes XML, Word, TXT, PDF, RAR, ZIP . My report can be wonderful if it is possible to display the way i requested. Is it possible if you could please download the screenshot i have attached in my question, maybe you could zoom and it can help you to understand more