# to replace the new file with the old while organizing the files into folders

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

The below mentioned code successfully organizes the files in folders and then in subfolders format wise automatically. However, i just need one help that is if a file already exists in a subfolder and the same file was added again, it should kill the previously saved file and add the newly update file. Currently it gives error as "File Already Exist" however I really would like to request if please anyone can amend the code.

I have tried and searched on internet but unsuccessful. Please find the code below

```
Sub OrganizeFilesByFileType()

    Const iFolderPath As String = "G:\!Archive Management\2023" ' adjust!!!
    
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "G:\!Archive Management\2023\"
    
If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim FolderPaths As Collection
    
Set FolderPaths = CollSubfolderPaths(FolderPath)
    
    MoveFilesToTypeFolders FolderPaths

End Sub


Function PickFolder( _
   
 Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _

    Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _

    Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK", _

    Optional ByVal ShowCancelMessage As Boolean = True) _

As String
    
    Dim FolderPath As String, IsFolderPicked As Boolean
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        .Title = DialogTitle

        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName

        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator

        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then

            FolderPath = InitialFolderPath

            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep

            .InitialFileName = FolderPath

        End If

        If .Show Then

            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)

            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep

            IsFolderPicked = True

        End If

    End With

    
    If IsFolderPicked Then PickFolder = FolderPath: Exit Function
        
    If ShowCancelMessage Then
        MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, "Pick Folder"
    End If

End Function
```

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of a folder ('FolderPath')
'               and all of its subfolders in a collection.
' Remarks:      Check it only against 'Nothing' (its count cannot be 0).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function CollSubfolderPaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _
As Collection
    Const ProcName As String = "CollSubFolderPaths"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function
    
    Dim collPaths As Collection: Set collPaths = New Collection
    
    Dim collQueue As Collection: Set collQueue = New Collection
    collQueue.Add FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    Dim fsoFolder As Object
    Dim fsoSubfolder As Object

    Do Until collQueue.Count = 0
        Set fsoFolder = collQueue(1)
        collQueue.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
        collPaths.Add fsoFolder.Path
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
            collQueue.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
        Next fsoSubfolder
    Loop
      
    If Not IncludeFolderPath Then
        If collPaths.Count = 1 Then Exit Function
        collPaths.Remove 1
    End If
    
    Set CollSubfolderPaths = collPaths

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

```
Sub MoveFilesToTypeFolders( _
        ByVal FolderPaths As Collection, _
        Optional ByVal ShowMessage As Boolean = True)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Files To Type Folders"
    
    Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Keys: Type Folder Paths (New), Items: True or False i.e. exists or not
    Dim foDict As Object: Set foDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    foDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    ' Keys: File Paths (Old), Items: Type File Paths (New)
    Dim fiDict As Object: Set fiDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    fiDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Item, fsoFolder As Object, fsoFile As Object
    Dim FolderName As String, FileType As String, TypePath As String
    
    For Each Item In FolderPaths
        Set fsoFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Item)
        FolderName = fsoFolder.Name
        For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
            FileType = fsoFile.Type
            If StrComp(FolderName, FileType, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                TypePath = FSO.BuildPath(Item, FileType)
                If Not foDict.Exists(TypePath) Then
                    foDict(TypePath) = FSO.FolderExists(TypePath)
                End If
                fiDict(fsoFile.Path) = FSO.BuildPath(TypePath, fsoFile.Name)
            'Else ' the file is already in its type folder; do nothing
            End If
        Next fsoFile
    Next Item
    
    ' Create the folders.
    For Each Item In foDict.Keys
        If Not foDict(Item) Then FSO.CreateFolder Item
    Next Item

    ' Move the files.
    For Each Item In fiDict.Keys
        Debug.Print Item, fiDict(Item)
        FSO.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)
    Next Item

    If ShowMessage Then
        If fiDict.Count > 0 Then
           
        Else
            
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You keep asking this kind of question so many times... And always received answers solving the issue. The basic logic of it is to check if the file exists and delete/`kill` it for such a case. You did not specify on which `Sub`/code  line the error is raised, but in that case you need a preview code line killing the file before moving the new one. Something as `If fso.FileExists(destFold & fileName) then kill destFold & fileName`. And only after it use something as `FSO.MoveFile source & FileName, destFold & FileName`. You should try understanding the answers you receive and **learn**...

Comment: Dear @FaneDuru I have tried to add kill command by adding the lines you have suggested in your previous solutions multiple times but not successful, it sometimes says missing IF and sometimes Loop, therefore finally i have decided to seek help. because the whole project is completed just left with this part which i just raised

Comment: When i Debug it gives the error at line  FSO.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)

Comment: I have added your both lines after the line i have mentioned above, it still says "File Already Exists"

Comment: Edit your question's code, to show your revised version.

Comment: Then, try `If fso.FileExists(fiDict(Item)) then kill  fiDict(Item)`, followed by existing code line  `FSO.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)`. Then, when you try something according to a received recommendation, it is  not enough to say "not successful"... You should edit your question and **show what exactly you tried**. In this way you will learn about what was wrong in the way you tried and how is better to proceed. This way will better fix the issue in your mind, I think.

Comment: @FunThomas He looks to be an unexperienced guy, but having logic in what he tries doing. I remotely connected to his computer and, like I said, he is able to understand. It looks he does not dare enough to fight for his own solution...

Comment: Understood @FaneDuru I have deleted my comment.

Comment: @faneduru, please, please, do not give the answers in comments, it is so a waste of time viewing questions already solved when looking for unanswered questions

Comment: @wrbp A simple code line in not a real answer, in such a context, I think... I mostly tried convincing the OP to dare trying by his own and learn by trying.

Comment: @FaneDuru Today i have tried and successfully created the same function in another macro. Thanks for motivation

Comment: @FaneDuru, I saw your comment an I think it was a correct answer. But most important, think of the greater good, there are a lot of questions solved in the comments that distract people like you and me to find the ones that really need an answer, making the the whole site less efficient.  Salman, please post the corrected code as an answer, to remove this as an unanswered question and prevent getting attention of more people trying to help.

Comment: @wrbp i will post it in the morning tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub OrganizeFilesByFileType()

```
Const iFolderPath As String = "G:\!Archive Management\2023" ' adjust!!!

Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = "G:\!Archive Management\2023\"
```

If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

```
Dim FolderPaths As Collection
```

Set FolderPaths = CollSubfolderPaths(FolderPath)

```
MoveFilesToTypeFolders FolderPaths
```

End Sub

Function PickFolder( _

Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _

```
Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _

Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK", _

Optional ByVal ShowCancelMessage As Boolean = True) _
```

As String

```
Dim FolderPath As String, IsFolderPicked As Boolean

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    .Title = DialogTitle

    .ButtonName = DialogButtonName

    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator

    If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then

        FolderPath = InitialFolderPath

        If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep

        .InitialFileName = FolderPath

    End If

    If .Show Then

        FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)

        If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep

        IsFolderPicked = True

    End If

End With


If IsFolderPicked Then PickFolder = FolderPath: Exit Function
    
If ShowCancelMessage Then
    MsgBox "Dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, "Pick Folder"
End If
```

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the paths of a folder ('FolderPath')
'               and all of its subfolders in a collection.
' Remarks:      Check it only against 'Nothing' (its count cannot be 0).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Function CollSubfolderPaths( _

ByVal FolderPath As String, _

Optional ByVal IncludeFolderPath As Boolean = True) _

As Collection

Const ProcName As String = "CollSubFolderPaths"

On Error GoTo ClearError

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not FSO.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then Exit Function

Dim collPaths As Collection: Set collPaths = New Collection

Dim collQueue As Collection: Set collQueue = New Collection
collQueue.Add FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

Dim fsoFolder As Object
Dim fsoSubfolder As Object

Do Until collQueue.Count = 0
    Set fsoFolder = collQueue(1)
    collQueue.Remove 1 ' dequeue!
    collPaths.Add fsoFolder.Path
    For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoFolder.SubFolders
        collQueue.Add fsoSubfolder ' enqueue!
    Next fsoSubfolder
Loop
  
If Not IncludeFolderPath Then
    If collPaths.Count = 1 Then Exit Function
    collPaths.Remove 1
End If

Set CollSubfolderPaths = collPaths
```

ProcExit:

```
Exit Function
```

ClearError:

Debug.Print "@" & ProcName & "@ Run-time error '" _

```
 & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
```

Resume ProcExit

End Function

Sub MoveFilesToTypeFolders( _

```
 ByVal FolderPaths As Collection, _

 Optional ByVal ShowMessage As Boolean = True)
```

Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Move Files To Type Folders"

```
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Keys: Type Folder Paths (New), Items: True or False i.e. exists or not
Dim foDict As Object: Set foDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
foDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

' Keys: File Paths (Old), Items: Type File Paths (New)
Dim fiDict As Object: Set fiDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
fiDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Dim Item, fsoFolder As Object, fsoFile As Object
Dim FolderName As String, FileType As String, TypePath As String

For Each Item In FolderPaths
    Set fsoFolder = FSO.GetFolder(Item)
    FolderName = fsoFolder.Name
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        FileType = fsoFile.Type
        If StrComp(FolderName, FileType, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            TypePath = FSO.BuildPath(Item, FileType)
            If Not foDict.Exists(TypePath) Then
                foDict(TypePath) = FSO.FolderExists(TypePath)
            End If
            fiDict(fsoFile.Path) = FSO.BuildPath(TypePath, fsoFile.Name)
        'Else ' the file is already in its type folder; do nothing
        End If
    Next fsoFile
Next Item

' Create the folders.
For Each Item In foDict.Keys
    If Not foDict(Item) Then FSO.CreateFolder Item
Next Item

 ' Move the files.
For Each Item In fiDict.Keys
    Debug.Print Item, fiDict(Item)
    If FSO.FileExists(fiDict(Item)) Then Kill fiDict(Item)
    FSO.MoveFile Item, fiDict(Item)
Next Item
If ShowMessage Then
    If fiDict.Count > 0 Then
       
    Else
        
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).