# Most efficient way to loop thru a column searching for a specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that I want to search thru a row of column names (row 7) and identify whether or not the column name is part of a list I have. If it detects that it is part of the list, then it will go down that column and convert the formulas to values by doing `Sheet.Range.Value=Sheet.Range.Value`.

For example, if it detects the word Apple or Banana, it will loop thru the column and convert the formulas into values.

However, I have found that this probably isn't the most efficient way to achieve this. I have the code listed below. Does anyone know how to make this more efficient?

```
Dim lastcol, lastrow As Long

    lastcol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim z
    For i = 5 To lastcol
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Banana" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Apple" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Coconut" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Kiwi" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Watermelon" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).value = "Orange" Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).value
            Next z
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: In your nested `For z = 9 to lastRow`, I'm pretty sure you can remove that and just do `Range(Cells(9,i),cells(lastRow,i)).Value = Range(Cells(9,i),cells(lastRow,i)).Value` and set those all in one go.  Also, you can use `Else If`, instead of `End If`, since with `If / ... / End If / If / ... / End If`will check every `If` condition.  Assuming a cell is one value, you could do `If [cell].Value = "Banana" Then / [that range formula above] / ElseIf [cell].Value = "Apple" / ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of search words (`arrWords`) as an alternative solution, and then check if a given header (`Cells(7,i).Value`) belongs to this array (`Application.Match`):

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lastcol As Long, lastrow As Long, z As Long
    Dim arrWords As Variant

    arrWords = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Coconut", "Kiwi", "Watermelon", "Orange")
    lastcol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lastcol
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, i).Value, arrWords, 0)) Then
            For z = 9 To lastrow
                Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(z, i).Value
            Next z
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

As per Bruce's suggestion, you can also replace your whole `For z = 9 to lastrow ... Next z` loop with one line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(lastrow, i)).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(lastrow, i)).Value
```

Comment: Clever using `Match()`.  You could also change that `For` loop and just have a one line `Range(Cells(7, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).Value = Range(Cells(7, i), Cells(lastRow, i)).Value`

Comment: @BruceWayne Nice one! It would be even more efficient then.

Comment: Per Bruce's suggestion, I added it in yet am having an Object not defined error. To test out where the error would be, I replaced `Range(Cells(9, i), Cells(lastrow, i))` with `Range("F1:F48")` and it ran without an error. So it seems like defining range with the cells seems to be throwing an issue. Any idea as to why? @BruceWayne @JustynaMK

Comment: @tokyo_north You'll get that error if `Sheet1` is NOT your currently active sheet.  This is because you don't fully qualify your `Cells` references inside the `Range` argument, which makes the `Cells` default to the ActiveSheet.  Because `Range` is qualified to `Sheet1` and `Cells` are defaulting to ActiveSheet, if you have a different sheet selected you'll end up with that error.

Comment: @tigeravatar +1. I didn't have the sheet activated either, which was an issue. But thanks to all who helped. This proves to be very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array, and check the value of the array.

This is a little longer than @JustynaMK's answer, but I was working on it before they posted their, so figure I'll go ahead and post.

```
Option Explicit

Sub replace_formulas()
Dim keys() As Variant
Dim keyWords As String

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

keys = Array("Banana", "Apple", "Coconut", "Kiwi", "Watermelon", "Orange")
keyWords = joinArray(keys, "#")

Dim headerRow As Long, startCol As Long
headerRow = 7
startCol = 5

Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
lastCol = ws.Cells(headerRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
' I changed this to Column 5 to get the lastRow, but change as needed
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, startCol).End(xlUp).Row

Dim headers As Range
Set headers = ws.Range(ws.Cells(headerRow, startCol), ws.Cells(headerRow, lastCol))

Dim cel As Range
With ws
    For Each cel In headers
        If InStr(1, keyWords, "#" & cel.Value & "#", vbTextCompare) Then
            .Range(.Cells(headerRow, cel.Column), .Cells(lastRow, cel.Column)).Value = _
            .Range(.Cells(headerRow, cel.Column), .Cells(lastRow, cel.Column)).Value
        End If
    Next cel
End With

End Sub

Function joinArray(arr As Variant, delim As String) As String
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112615/4650297
Dim strg As String
strg = Join(arr, delim)
joinArray = delim & strg
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you store your list as an array on a sheet, then there are a variety of ways of testing whether something is in the list.

A1 = apple A2 = banana A3 = missing B1 = TRUE B2 = TRUE B3 = FALSE

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH("apple",A1:A2,0))` returns TRUE

`=ISNUMBER(MATCH("orange",A1:A2,0))` returns FALSE

`=vlookup("apple",A1:A3,1)="apple"` returns TRUE.

`=vlookup("orange",A1:A3,1)="orange"` returns FALSE.

`=not(vlookup("apple",A1:A3,1)="missing")` returns TRUE.

`=not(vlookup("orange",A1:A3,1)="missing")` returns FALSE.

`=vlookup("apple",A1:B3,2)` returns TRUE.

`=vlookup("orange",A1:B3,2)` returns FALSE.