# Is an array inside a select case statement possible?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, select-case

I just want to know if it is possible for me to assign an array and use it as a qualifier inside a case statement?

```
Sub AccountCopy()
Dim Criteria1 As Variant
Dim Criteria2 As Variant
Dim Acct As Variant
Dim NR As Integer

Criteria1 = Array("Checking", "Savings")
Criteria2 = Array("Loans", "Credit Card")

MonthSheet.Range("T1") = "Title"
MonthSheet.Range("U1") = "Account"
MonthSheet.Range("V1") = "Description"
MonthSheet.Range("W1") = "Amount"
MonthSheet.Range("X1") = "Date"
MonthSheet.Range("Y1") = "Category"

With Range("T1:Y1")
    .Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Font.Size = 8
    .Font.Bold = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Style = "Title"
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With



For Each Acct In [AccountNameList]
    Select Case Acct.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Case Is = Criteria1
            NR = Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next Row
            'MonthSheet.Range 
        Case Criteria2
    End Select
```

Don't criticize me too hard, I'm still pretty new to this.  I don't post on fourms very often, but their are some really talented people on here and I thought who better to ask then the people that have been coding for years?  Thanks in advance!

This is what I want to accomplish:
I want to define the "Criteria1" Array to how ever many dimensions I so desire.  Perhaps I want to add a third criteria to the list.  Rather than going and changing the case statement, I would rather just add to the array later on down the line to include that additional qualifier.  Perhaps I've set the wrong type?  I don't know?  I feel like this can be done rather easy but I am missing a very small detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Some remarks:**

1. You are defining a 1 dimension array and you don't need a two/three dimensional array to accomplish what you want. Check [Mathieu's tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/17455/multidimensional-arrays) to learn about this
2. Always [fully qualify](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/5110/qualifying-references) the objects to avoid code unexpected behaviors
3. Indent your code (you can use the free [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) to help you with that)
4. What you want is totally doable...in different ways, one is just use a helper function to find the match in an array.

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

**Helper function option**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AccountCopy()

    Dim Criteria1 As Variant
    Dim Criteria2 As Variant
    Dim Acct As Variant ' This can be declared as a Range
    Dim NR As Integer ' Better to name the variables to something readable like: newRow

    ' Added this new variable
    Dim accountValue As String

    Criteria1 = Array("Checking", "Savings")
    Criteria2 = Array("Loans", "Credit Card")

    MonthSheet.Range("T1") = "Title"
    MonthSheet.Range("U1") = "Account"
    MonthSheet.Range("V1") = "Description"
    MonthSheet.Range("W1") = "Amount"
    MonthSheet.Range("X1") = "Date"
    MonthSheet.Range("Y1") = "Category"

    ' This next line should be something like: <TheCodeNameOfTheSheet>.Range("T1:Y1") to be fully qualified
    With Range("T1:Y1")
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = 8
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Style = "Title"
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With


    ' In here, it's easier to understand if you use Thisworkbook.Names("AccountNameList")
    For Each Acct In [AccountNameList]

        ' Store the account next cell's value
        accountValue = Acct.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Select Case True
        Case IsInArray(accountValue, Criteria1)
            ' Do something
            Debug.Print "Something", Acct.Offset(0, 1).Address
        Case IsInArray(accountValue, Criteria2)
            ' Do something else
            Debug.Print "Something else", Acct.Offset(0, 1).Address
        End Select

    Next Acct

End Sub

Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/1521579
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Another approach is to loop through the array items

with something like this...

**Add this inside the for each loop**

*needs a `dim counter as long` somewhere in the code*

```
For counter = 0 To UBound(Criteria1)
    If Acct.Offset(0, 1).Value = Criteria1(counter) Then
        ' Do something
        Debug.Print "Something", Acct.Offset(0, 1).Address
    End If
Next counter

For counter = 0 To UBound(Criteria2)
    If Acct.Offset(0, 1).Value = Criteria2(counter) Then
        ' Do something else
        Debug.Print "Something else", Acct.Offset(0, 1).Address
    End If
Next counter
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo for the feedback.  I knew there was another way to do this however I was trying to avoid a loop statement or a function.  I appreciate your help either way.  I was hoping I could have used the array within the case function without going outside of it.  However, it seems like I cannot.

Comment: AFAIK this is the way.

Comment: Yeah - sometimes an idea is just an idea.  Being that I am still learning, this was a good opportunity to expand my understanding.  It may not be ideal, but at lease I can stand up my code a little further - Thanks!

Comment: Excellent. If this solves your question, mark it so others may find it too