# VBA code for multiple if statements within an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, split, select-case

I am trying to split the array in column B which is separated by commas and then look for each item and if the condition is satisfied then publish something in column C.

I have lot of scenarios with combination of both AND/OR conditions.
At the end if none of scenarios is satisfied then in column "C" it should be "not defined".

```vb
Dim Cl As Range
Dim Dic As Object
Dim Sp As Variant
Dim i As Long
  
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
With Sheets("Analysis")
    For Each Cl In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Sp = Split(Cl.Offset(, 1).Value, ",")
        Select Case Cl.Offset(, 1).Value
            Case Is = " "
                C1.Offset(, 2).Value = " "
            Case Is = "Production"
                C1.Offset(, 2).Value = "Prod"
            Case Is = "Production" And "Development" Or "Training"
                C1.Offset(, 2).Value = "Dev/Prod"
        End Select
    Next Cl
End With
End Sub
```

Sample data where column A has Id and column B has category.

| ID | CATEGORY |
| --- | --- |
| 131 | Production |
| 124 | Production, Development, Staging, Test, Training, UserAcceptanceTest |
| 283 | Development, Test |
| 1138 | empty. |

I am looking for below result in column "C" for the below mentioned scenarios.
If Category column is as below then Column "C" values should be the one after "-".

1. empty - No
2. Development - Dev
3. Production - Prod
4. Test - Test
5. Staging - Staging
6. Training - Training
7. UserAcceptanceTest - UAT
8. Development AND Test AND Production OR any other category - All
9. Development AND Test OR any other category (Except Production) - Dev/Test
10. Test AND Production OR any other category (Except Development) - Dev/Test
11. Development AND any other category (Except Production and Test ) - Dev
12. Production AND any other category (Except Development and Test ) - Prod
13. Test AND any other category (Except Development and Production) - Test
14. any other scenario - Not Defined

Comment: Would really help your question to show some sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: You can edit your question, and format the data as it would appear on the sheet.

Comment: Have a look at [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/9538700)

Comment: Hi horst, that seems to be to search for a single string in an array but I have to look for multiple strings with AND and OR conditions which I am finding difficult to do.

Comment: yes, just use the `IsInArray`Function multiple times in an `If` or `case` Statement. Like `If IsInArray("Foo", arr) And IsInArray("Bar", arr) Then...`

Comment: Thank you Horst, do we need to split the array if we are using IsInArray? Can you help me on how to iterate and through each array in column B and produce result in column C. I can re-use write all my conditions. And how to validate a case where only the string we are searching is in the array and nothing else.

Comment: Do 2-7 mean only one entry? Could you clarify (do a rethink) on 8-13 i.e. 8. Development, Test, Anything, 9. Development, Anything (except) 10. Test, Anything (except) which would mean something different if you would replace the ORs with ANDs. Is the order set in 8-13? Think about `equal` and `contains`.

Comment: I don't think that this will work without sample data that will clearly show all the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function `IsInArray` from [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11112305/9538700):

I filled it with some example cases to give you the idea how to do it.

```
Sub Category()

For Each cl In Range("A2:A" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    Sp = Split(tempString , ", ")

    Select Case True    
        Case UBound(Sp) = -1
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "No"
        Case UBound(Sp) = 0 And Sp(0) = " "
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "No"
        Case UBound(Sp) = 0 And Sp(0) = "Development"
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Dev"
        Case IsInArray("Development", Sp) And IsInArray("Test", Sp) And IsInArray("Production", Sp)
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "All"
        Case IsInArray("Development", Sp) And Not IsInArray("Production", Sp) And Not IsInArray("Test", Sp)
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Dev"
        Case Else
            cl.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Not Defined"
    End Select

Next cl
End Sub


Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi horst, that works like a gem except for the line - Case UBound(Sp) = 0 And Sp(0) = " " it is throwing Run-tume error '9': Subscript out of range . Until it finds the first empty cell in category it is running great.

Comment: I added a case for an empty cell  `ubound(Sp) = -1`