# checking if value present in array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-ms-access-vba-array) question, however, it doesn't seem to work in my case.

Basically, this script is going through a column selecting distinct values and populating array `arr` with them. First `If` is checking if the column has ended, then to avoid calling empty array I have the first `IfElse`, and finally I want to check a non-empty array for `cell` string. If it is not present, I want to add it.

```
Public Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function

Sub SelectDistinct()

    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cells As Range

    Set cells = Worksheets("types").Columns("A").Cells

    i = 0
    For Each cell In cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf i = 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = cell
            i = i + 1
        ElseIf IsInArray(cell.Value, arr) = False Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(UBound(arr)) = cell
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

For some reason, it throws "Subscript out of range" error on the call of `IsInArray` function. Can someone let me know where I went wrong?

Comment: If your array is only 1 column, you could just use `If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, arr, False))` to check if the value already exists in the array.

Comment: David, you mean one row?

Comment: @sashkello yes, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do it for a one-dimensional array, using the `Application.Match` function, instead of another UDF.

I have consolidated some of your If/ElseIf logic with a `Do...While` loop, and then use the `Match` function to check whether cell value exists in the array. If it does not exist, then add it to the array and continue to the next cell in your range.

```
Sub SelectDistinct()

Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim cells As Range
Dim cl As Range
Dim foundCl As Boolean

    Set cells = Worksheets("Sheet6").Columns(1).cells

    Set cl = cells.cells(1)

    Do
        If IsError(Application.Match(cl.Value, arr, False)) Then
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = cl
            i = i + 1
        Else:
            'Comment out the next line to completely ignore duplicates'
            MsgBox cl.Value & " already exists!"

        End If

        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop While Not IsEmpty(cl.Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this script. However, it seems not to work in my case. Might it be necessary to use some initialization for arr()? Help highly appreciated! Best

Comment: @Fabian Stolz please ask a new question for the problem you're having.  Remember to include the code you are using and describe what is/is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your "Subscript out of range" error on the call of `IsInArray` function" question is that the variable `arr` is dimmed as `Variant`.  For the `Filter` function to work in the `IsInArray` UDF `arr` must be dimmed as a `String`.

You can try the following code which 1) Sets up a filtered `String` array, and 2) avoids placing `Redim Preserve` (which is a costly function) in a loop:

```
Sub FilteredValuesInArray()
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027095/checking-if-value-present-in-array
Dim rng As Range
Dim arrOriginal() As Variant, arrFilteredValues() As String
Dim arrTemp() As String
Dim strPrintMsg As String    'For debugging
Dim i As Long, lCounter As Long

Set rng = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion    'You can adjust this how you want
arrOriginal = rng

'Convert variant array to string array
ReDim arrTemp(LBound(arrOriginal) - 1 To UBound(arrOriginal) - 1)
For i = LBound(arrOriginal) To UBound(arrOriginal)
    arrTemp(i - 1) = CStr(arrOriginal(i, 1))
Next i

'Setup filtered values array
ReDim arrFilteredValues(LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp))

On Error Resume Next
Do
    arrFilteredValues(lCounter) = arrTemp(0)
    'Save non matching values to temporary array
    arrTemp = Filter(arrTemp, arrTemp(0), False)
    'If error all unique values found; exit loop
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
    lCounter = lCounter + 1
Loop Until lCounter >= UBound(arrFilteredValues)
On Error GoTo 0
'Resize array to proper bounds
ReDim Preserve arrFilteredValues(LBound(arrFilteredValues) To lCounter - 1)

'====DEBUG CODE
For i = LBound(arrFilteredValues) To UBound(arrFilteredValues)
    strPrintMsg = strPrintMsg & arrFilteredValues(i) & vbCrLf
Next i
Debug.Print vbTab & "Filtered values are:" & vbCrLf & strPrintMsg
'====END DEBUG CODE
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy yet dirty hack :

```
Function InStringArray(str As String, a As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim flattened_a As String
    flattened_a = ""

    For Each s In a
        flattened_a = flattened_a & "-" & s
    Next

    If InStr(flattened_a, str) > 0 Then
        InStringArray = True
    Else
        InStringArray = False
    End If
End Function
```