# Checking if Value is Present in an Array

Tags: arrays, vba

I modified the VBA code found at 
[checking if value present in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027095/checking-if-value-present-in-array) to the code below.  A user will choose a field name and I want the code to find the column that field is listed in and create an array of all items in that column, but I want each non-blank value to show up only once in the array.  I don't want any duplicates.

For example, if the column has values A, B, A, C, D, I want the code to return the array as A, B, C, D.

I get a run time error 13 - Type mismatch on this line of the code:

```
If cell.Value <> "" And IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(cell.Value, MyArray, 0)) Then
```

I'm confused, because it seems like all my data types are correct.  Can anyone offer any help?

```
Sub ChangeBlock()

Dim MyArray() As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim i As Integer

If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("Block1")) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

ColNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value, Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A1:AG1"), 0)

    For Each cell In Sheets("Budget Table").Columns(ColNum)
        If cell.Value <> "" And IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(cell.Value, MyArray, 0)) Then
            ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)
            MyArray(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End If

MsgBox (MyArray)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error 13 Type mismatch is caused here:

`cell.Value <> ""`

The `Value` here is 2D-array something like (1 To 1048576, 1 To 1) and it is not possible to compare this array to a string hence the type mismatch.

*Edit:*

---

Actually the variable `cell` *is a column* so to compare properly it is necessary to say what element of the array is compared, e.g. for the first element:

`cell.Value()(1, 1) = ""`

More correct would be to rename the variable `cell` to e.g. `oneColumn` because the variable `cell` actually contains a reference to a column, e.g. like this:

```
Dim myColumns As Range
Set myColumns = Sheets("Budget Table").Columns(ColNum)

Dim oneColumn As Range

For Each oneColumn In myColumns
    ' ...
Next oneColumn
```

*Note: Here the `for-each` does not make sense because `myColumns` references just one column and `myColumns.Columns.Count` returns `1`. So all you wanted was actually `myColumns.Cells` which returns all the cells of the column.*

The value of `oneColumn` is 2D-array and to be honest I don't know why it is 2D and not just 1D either. When you would examine `Value` of e.g. `Range("A1:C3")` then you see it returns 2D-array which is understandable. But why one column of columns returns 2D as well? Seems to be odd to me as well :). An example of 1D-array would be `Dim oneDArray: oneDArray = Array("A", "B", "C")`. As far as I know 1D-array is never returned from a `Range.Value` property. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152288) interesting article about array dimensions in VBA.

---

But this is not necessary because each `Range` has a property `Cells`. So here the `Columns(ColNum).Cells` should be used.

The complete code could look something like the following but it is a little bit too complicated. First the array has a lot of empty elements because the whole column is used and second consider the solution with a dictionary like @A.S.H is proposing. HTH

```
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim ColNum As Integer
Dim i As Integer

ReDim MyArray(0 To 0)

With Sheets("Budget Table")

    If Intersect(ActiveCell, .Range("Block1")) Is Nothing Then _
        Exit Sub

    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then _
        Exit Sub

    ColNum = Application.Match(ActiveCell.Value, .Range("A1:AG1"), 0)

    For Each cell In .Columns(ColNum).Cells
        If cell.Value = "" Then _
            GoTo continue

        If IsError(Application.Match(cell.Value, MyArray, 0)) Then
            If i > 0 Then
                ReDim Preserve MyArray(i)
            End If

            MyArray(i) = cell.Value
            i = i + 1

        End If
continue:
    Next cell

End With
```

Comment: Thanks, dee.  I have a question, though:  why is the value a 2D array?  In my mind, one column of data in excel would be the best example of a 1D array.  If that's actually a 2D array, what's an example of a 1D array then?  Can it exist in an excel spreadsheet?  Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Or are you saying that the value object returns a 2D array while the cell object returns a 1D array?  

Sorry if I'm not understanding something.  I think I'm getting confused when you say:  "Actually the variable cell in a column so to compare properly" @dee

Comment: I had a TYPO there, ```Actually the variable cell 'in'``` should be ```Actually the variable cell 'is'```. See the edited answer, HTH.

Answer (score 2):

To use `IsError`, use `Application.Match` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Although these two methods are similar, the way they handle errors is slightly different. The former returns an error variant that you can test with `IsError`, while the latter just `throws` an error that you can only catch with an error-handling mechanism.

Finally, if your data is large, this is not the optimal way to do the checking for duplicates; you should think of using a `Dictionary`.

Comment: I tried that also and I got the same error.  I probably wouldn't be going through more than 200,000 cells.  Is that considered large?  I'll look into using a Dictionary.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, I also noticed that I can't find a reference to Application.Match in my VBE object browser.  Am I suppose to add a reference to a library in order to use the method?

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I placed a Debug.Print MyArray in front of the line I was getting the error on and noticed I would get the same error when running the code, but it would highlight the MyArray variable.  So, I tried changing the MyArray data type to variant, but still got the same error.  Does anyone have any guidance on why that would still happen?  From what I've read on the internet, changing the data type to variant should solve this. @A.S.H

Comment: No you dont need to add any reference. `Application.Match` (like many other Application methods) do not appear in the browser but they are available, you only have to type them. And yes, 200,000 cells is huge, big enough to justify the optimization of the function, using a `Dictionary`. The "amateur" method envisaged so far is extremely slow for such large data.