# To check if a string contains an element from a list (of strings)

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to do that in VBA other than manually looping through the array and testing each element separately?

Comment: Are you asking is there a way of testing if any sub-string, within array of sub-strings, exists within a string with running a loop? If so, I don't believe there is

Comment: @LucasSeveryn  you can use a `For` loop, and check each member of the list of strings (using `Instr` function for instance). Another option is using the `Match` function. But you need to provide more data, or upload your latest code attempt

Answer (score 1):

Check out A.S.H's answer below, `Application.Match` is the way to go.  This will throw `Error 2042` if the element is not in the array.

Answer mentioned:
[Checking if Value is Present in an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468801/checking-if-value-is-present-in-an-array)

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb239415(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: When I tried this method `Application.Match` returned error `13 - Type Mismatch` while `Worksheetfunction.Match` returned error `1004 - Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class`.  Error 1004 would be more specific in an error handler, while `Application.Match` could return the boolean exists/not exists value with `bExists = Not (IsError(Application.Match("MyValueString", vMyArray, 0)))` (rather than put it in an `IF...END IF` block to check for an error).