# excel 2010 vba loop pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, loops, pivot-table

I have 16 pivot tables that I need to update when the user presses a button. The code that needs to run is as follows:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("scrap code").ClearAllFilters
               ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("count")
            .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        End With
```

The names of the pivot tables are:
`MSP,MSP30,FSP,FSP30,MRP,MRP30,FRP,FRP30,MPP,MPP30,FPP,FPP30,MCP,MCP30,FCP,FCP30`

I'd like to replace `PivotTable10` with a variable that loops thru that list of pivot tables. Right now my code is 16 blocks of the code above. I know little about loops and I haven't found a good example of this type of loop in my google searches.

EDIT: finally code that worked, both answers below worked perfectly, this code just worked slightly faster

```
Sub IteratePivots()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next

Worksheets("Analytics Admin").Activate

Dim pvtTables As PivotTables
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Set pvtTables = Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For Each pvtTable In pvtTables
    pvtTable.PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
    pvtTable.PivotFields("scrap code").ClearAllFilters
    pvtTable.PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

    With pvtTable.PivotFields("count")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
    End With
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Only Pivottable names alone are going to change in you code am i right?

Comment: that is correct I'd run those exact 4 lines each time ( I may have to add an error correction for when the only value is 0) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. This code will iterates through all the pivotable in your sheet.

```
Sub IteratePivots()
Dim pvtTables As PivotTables
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Set pvtTables = Application.ActiveSheet.PivotTables
For Each pvtTable In pvtTables
    pvtTable.PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
    pvtTable.PivotFields("scrap code").ClearAllFilters
    pvtTable.PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

    With pvtTable.PivotFields("count")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks this works slightly faster then @hambones code, by like 6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit of a hack, but something like this might to the trick:

```
  Dim pt As PivotTable
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim names As Variant
  Dim found As Boolean

  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  names = Split("MSP,MSP30,FSP,FSP30,MRP,MRP30,FRP,FRP30,MPP,MPP30,FPP,FPP30,MCP,MCP30,FCP,FCP30", ",")

  For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    found = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(names)
      If pt.Name = names(i) Then
        found = True
      End If
    Next i

    If found Then
      pt.PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
      pt.PivotFields("scrap code").ClearAllFilters
      pt.PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

      pt.PivotFields("count").PivotItems("0").Visible = False
    End If

  Next pt
```

You may notice my clumsy check to see if the name is in the array...  This is a much better solution for that piece:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952705/190829

Comment: this is damn close to what I was trying to do, the only issues is that some of the pivot tables only value is 0 , and I get an error `unable to set the visible property of the PivotItem class`.

Comment: @AlbertoBrown, In that case  Check, if the value<>0 before you proceed.