# Adding to arrays and finding values in arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 arrays:  one that has values to search a document for (`arr`) and one that will put in associated cell addresses with the found values (`arr2`).  I have no issues with `arr`, and have used it earlier in my code successfully.

With `arr2`, I want to find any cells that contain the values in `arr`, and add the cell address `lRow` amount of rows down from it to `arr2`, but ONLY if that address isn't already in `arr2`.

I found 2 SO answers that I'm trying to combine in order to solve my issue, but so far with no luck.

[Excel VBA - adding an element to the end of an array](https://superuser.com/questions/808798/excel-vba-adding-an-element-to-the-end-of-an-array)

[How to search for string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-an-array)

My code below:

```
Sub Initiate()

Dim arr(3) As Variant
    arr(0) = "Value1"
    arr(1) = "Value2"
    arr(2) = "Value3"
    arr(3) = "Value4"
Dim arr2() As Variant
Dim Alc as String
Dim lRow as Long
Dim fVal as String

lRow = Activesheet.Cells(Activesheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each element In arr

fVal = element

Set fRange = WA.Cells.Find(What:=fVal, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

While Not fRange Is Nothing

    While Not IsInArray(fRange.Offset(lRow - 6, 0).Address(False, False), arr2)

        ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To UBound(arr2) + 1) As Variant

        arr2(UBound(arr2)) = fRange.Offset(lRow - 6, 0).Address(False, False)

    Set fRange = WA.Cells.Find(What:=fVal, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    Wend

Wend

Next element

Alc = "="

    For Each element In arr2

        Alc = Alc & element & "+"

    Next element

Alc = Left(Alc, Len(Alc) - 1)

MsgBox Alc

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr2 As Variant) As Boolean

    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr2, stringToBeFound)) > -1)

End Function
```

When run I get the following error:

[image]

On this line of code (within the `IsInArray` function):

`IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr2, stringToBeFound)) > -1)`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary to replace `arr2`. If you store the unique value as the key, you can protect against duplication relatively easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't like using Filter because it also matches on *substrings*, and often that's not what you want

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr2 As Variant) As Boolean

    IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr2, 0))

End Function
```

Also:

```
ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To UBound(arr2) + 1) As Variant
```

should probably be:

```
ReDim Preserve arr2(0 To UBound(arr2) + 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured I'd add in my comment here as an answer. (I hope it's not outside the scope of this question/forum). If you're looking to store unique values in a collection, I'm not sure that you can beat the performance of a dictionary.

Outside of the loop, you would declare and instantiate the `Dictionary`:

```
Dim oDict as Object
Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

The code that you currently use to search `arr2` then add the value if unique would be amended to look something like:

```
If Not oDict.Exists(fRange.Offset(lRow - 6), 0).Address(False, False)) then
    oDict(fRange.Offset(lRow - 6), 0).Address(False, False)) = ""
End If

Set fRange = WA.Cells.Find(What:=fVal, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

I don't know how many records you expect to be inserting or searching through, or how performant your software needs to be, but performance can be significantly different.