# Find unmatched strings between 2 arrays vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get unmatched strings in 2 arrays. I've tried this [How to search for string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-an-array][1]) , but they return true or false.

```
dim arr1 as variant
dim arr2 as variant

arr1 = "abc,def,ghi,jkl"
arr2 = "abc,def,ghi,jkl,pre,ec,vw"
```

But i'm trying to get the strings like
*result="pre,ec,vw"*
How to specify that in vba

Comment: Those are strings, not arrays. Did you mean   `arr1 = Array("abc","def,"ghi","jkl")` etc  ?

Comment: @sam are you looking to find unmatched strings and the result is a string ? (if that's the case you don't need to insert these string into arrays) . Or are you trying to compare String elements inside 2 arrays, and the result should be the unique array elements ?

Comment: Have you considered using SQL to implement the same? Just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
result=replace(arr2,arr1,"")
```

to list substrings that are in arr2 but not in arr1

```
Sub aargh()
    arr1 = "abc,def,ghi,jkl"
    arr2 = "abc,def,ghi,zer,jkl,pre,ec,vw"
    a = Split(arr1, ",")
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        arr2 = Replace(arr2, a(i), "")
    Next i
    ol = 0
    While Len(arr2) <> ol
        ol = Len(arr2)
        arr2 = Replace(arr2, ",,", ",")
    Wend
    If Left(arr2, 1) = "," Then arr2 = Mid(arr2, 2)
    MsgBox arr2
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the second parameter should be arr1 in the replace function. Also, I don't think this accounts for the leading `,`.

Comment: Initial message was posted with arr and arr2 and has been edited after my answer.

Comment: Ahh, that would explain it.