# How to delete a row that contain string on array

Tags: arrays, string, vba, loops, contain

I have a issue how to delete a row contain string on array. Here's my code

```
Dim brands As Variant

brands=Array("Test1","Test2","Test3")

For j=7 to 15
Cells(j,1).Select
If InStr(1,Cells(j,1).Value, brands,1)<> 0 Then
Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
j=j-1

End If
Next j
```

My issue is, let say I have hundred of string on the array. And in certain data, I need to delete rows that contain list of string on array.

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search for string in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951687/how-to-search-for-string-in-an-array)

Comment: So you want to make the search faster ?