# Why there is an error occuring with find function (through other lists)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a program that is supposed to copy some values from other workbooks and intially I set it up to take values from the specific sell.

For now I am trying to implement search function, not to inster the number of a column manually.

I am trying to use the following functions

```
Col = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Rows(2).Find("31.12.2018").Column
```

But even though, there is a specific value of 31.12.2018 in the file, it is still not working properly.

Also, it was somehow working, until I changed something and can't find the mistake for now. There is a problem as well, if the script doesn't find the data it goes to an error of undefinable object (seems like you can't assign .column, when there is no info found).

```
strFilter = "Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsb;*.xlsx),*.xls;*xlsb;*.xlsx"
strTitle = "Select input file (XXXX)"
arrfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(strFilter, 2, strTitle, , True)
If VarType(arrfiles) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub

Dim out As String
out = Cells(2, 7)
brow = Cells(2, 8)
bcol = Cells(2, 9)
Dim Target As Range
Dim Source As Range
Dim Col As Integer

For b = 1 To UBound(arrfiles)
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=arrfiles(b), UpdateLinks:=False)

lLastRow = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row 

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 1) = wb.Worksheets("Template").Cells(3, 3) 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 2) = wb.Worksheets("Template").Cells(2, 3) 

lLastRow = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
lLastRowCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Build").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row

For k = 2 To lLastRowCol

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 1) = wb.Worksheets("Template").Cells(3, 3) 
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 2) = wb.Worksheets("Template").Cells(2, 3) 
  Col = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Rows(2).Find("31.12.2018").Column

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 3) = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(2, Col)

  Set Target =ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 4), 

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(out).Cells(brow, 4 + lLastRow - 4))
  Set Source = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Range(wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(4, Col), wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Cells(lLastRow, Col))
  Source.Copy
  Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
  brow = brow + 1

Next k
```

Object undefined is the most common mistake, and also filetring for non-found values is also not working (not presented in a code above)

Comment: You will need to check if the value is null. If it is null give an error if it has a value do the script.

Comment: Well, As I said already, it somehow doesn't find the value even though it is there :/. And that's the main problem I am struggling right now

Comment: Why are you searching in Rows(2)? Is the value you want in the second row?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe Col = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Rows(2).Column.Find("31.12.2018")

or Col = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Rows(2).Find("31.12.2018")

Does the second one give you any results?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952705/5517161 maybe this will help you?

Comment: @Alexey, try `Col = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").UsedRange.Find("31.12.2018").Column`

Comment: a) Run a manual find in your worksheet and see if it finds your text. If it does then there is a problem with your code, else there is a problem with the text you are trying to find. b) When using `.Find()` it is preferred to explicitly define the `.LookAt` parameter too, read here for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: Yes, the data is in second row for sure.

Comment: `Find` returns a `Range` or a `Nothing`. You should **ALWAYS** test for `Nothing`ness, as otherwise there will always be an error when the value is not found. If row 2 contains *date* values formatted like `DD.MM.YYYY` then `Find` is likely to fail as date values are stored as numerics, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we are dealing with *dates* (and not with *strings* that look somehow like as date): What you see in your sheet is just the representation of a date (as defined with the number format of that cell). No matter how you display a date, it's internal value (a double) is always the same.

It is tricky to use the `Find`-Function for dates when you are not using US-settings. Best bet is to search for the internal number of the date by converting your search criteria to a date. Note that I split your `Find`-command into two statements: Code is more readable and it's much easier to debug.

```
Dim searchFor As Date
searchFor = DateValue("16.05.2019")   ' Method 1
searchFor = DateSerial(2019, 5, 16)   ' Method 2

dim resultRange as range, col as long
set resultRange = wb.Worksheets("Calculation").Rows(2).Find(searchFor)
if not resultRange is nothing then
    col = resultRange.Column
End If
```