# Execute few statements when the array is not empty in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, outlook, ms-word, navbar

So, whenever I am running this code, it is always going into the else block, even if there isn't any data in the array

```
    If IsEmpty(arr) Then 'want to check if the array is not empty
    Exit Sub
    Else
    statements.....
    endif
```

Comment: Take a look in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544936/7658533

Comment: I've used Not Not arr in my code, but then also it is going into if block even though my array doesn't have any values in it

Comment: I explicitly linked to a specific answer. This does not use the `not not` syntax.

Comment: Hey thank you for trying to help me, I am a beginner in vba, but on a macro, I am not understanding what you sent, could you help me with a code, that solve this problem

Comment: I want to execute few statements, when the array is not empty, so first i have used isempty(arr) function, but it always going into the else block, even if there is data or there isn't any data.

Comment: You need to copy the function `IsArrayAllocated` in your module and then use it like `If not IsArrayAllocated(arr) Then`.

Comment: tried using IsArrayAllocated function, no luck, it is again printing statements in both the cases, when there is data in the array and when the array is empty

Comment: What returns `IsArray(arr)`? Is `arr` even an array?

Comment: I tried this   Debug.Print IsArray(arr) and it is printing true and my array name is arr

Comment: What about `Debug.Print LBound(arr)` and `Debug.Print UBound(arr)`? What do they return?

Comment: Debug.Print LBound(arr) is 1, Debug.Print UBound(arr) is 4, but IsArray(arr) is returning true for both the cases like when there are values in the array and when there are not any values (Empty) in the array

Comment: Your array **is not empty**, because **it has elements** and so is initialized. If there are values inside the arrays elements is something different!

Comment: You need to understand this basics. Read this, there are some explanations and helper functions.

Comment: I was looping through the cells in 4 rows and 2 columns and putting those values in the array, but in my data, there are some cells where in those 4 rows and 2 columns are blank, so how should i get rid off those blank cells, I just want to execute statements when I have values in my array

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me @unhandled Exception, unfortunately i got stuck

Comment: You should open a new question and there post your relevant code.  Here it’s not possible without your code.