# VBA: What is causing this string argument passed to ParamArray to get changed to a number (that looks suspiciously like a pointer)?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-bug

FINAL EDIT: It does indeed appear to be a compiler bug - see the accepted answer.

Using VBA within Excel 2007, I have the following code in 'Class1':

```
Option Explicit

Public Function strange(dummy As String, ParamArray pa())
    Debug.Print pa(LBound(pa))
End Function

Public Sub not_strange(dummy As String, ParamArray pa())
    Debug.Print pa(LBound(pa))
End Sub

Public Function also_not_strange(ParamArray pa())
    Debug.Print pa(LBound(pa))
End Function
```

and some mode code in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function not_strange_either(dummy As String, ParamArray pa())
    Debug.Print pa(LBound(pa))
End Function

Public Sub outer(v)
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1

    Call c.strange("", v(LBound(v)))
    Call c.not_strange("", v(LBound(v)))
    Call c.also_not_strange(v(LBound(v)))

    Call not_strange_either("", v(LBound(v)))
End Sub
```

If call 'outer' from the Immediate window like this:

```
call outer(array("a"))
```

I get back output that seems strange:

```
 102085832 
a
a
a
```

It seems to matter whether the called routine is in a class module or not, whether it is a Sub or a Function, and whether or not there is an initial argument. Am I missing something about how VBA is supposed to work? Any ideas?

The strange number changes from run to run. I say "looks suspiciously like a pointer" because if I call this:

```
Public Sub outer2(v)
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1

    Dim ind As Long
    For ind = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
        Call c.strange("", v(ind))
    Next ind
End Sub
```

like so:

```
call outer2(array("a","b","c"))
```

I get back output like:

```
 101788312 
 101788328 
 101788344
```

It's the increment by 16 that makes me suspicious, but I really don't know. Also, passing a value, say by calling:

```
Call c.strange("", CStr(v(ind)))
```

works just fine.

EDIT: A little more info...If I assign the return value from 'c.strange' to something instead of throwing it away, I get the same behavior:

```
Public Sub outer3(v)
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1

    Dim x
    x = c.strange("", v(LBound(v)))

    Call c.not_strange("", v(LBound(v)))
    Call c.also_not_strange(v(LBound(v)))

    Call not_strange_either("", v(LBound(v)))
End Sub
```

Interestingly, if I call my test routines as above, with an argument that results from calling 'Array', the supposed-pointer value changes. However, if I call it like this:

```
call outer([{1,2,3}])
```

I get back the same number, even if I make the call repeatedly. (The number changes if I switch to another app in Windows, like my browser.) So, now I'm intrigued that the Excel evaluator (invoked with the brackets) seemingly caches its results...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now this is awesome.

Reproduced on office 2003.
Looks like a compiler bug.

The problem is in this line:

```
Call c.strange("", v(LBound(v)))
```

Here the compiler creates a `Variant` that holds a 1D array of `Variant`'s, the only element of which is a pointer instead of the value. This pointer then goes to the `strange` function which actually is not strange, it only prints the `Variant\Long` value passed to it.

This trick brings the compiler sanity back:

```
Call c.strange("", (v(LBound(v))))
```

---

EDIT

Yes, this magic number is a pointer to the VARIANT structure which is supposed to be passed to the `strange` method. The first field of which is `8`, which is `vbString`, and the data field contains a pointer to the actual string `"a"`.

Therefore, it is definitely a compiler bug... Yet another VB compiler bug in regard of arrays ;)

Comment: Yeah, it looks like a bug. Just some odd edge case...ParamArray, in a function, on a class, with another parameter in front, etc.... @GSerg, do you have any inside knowledge of the VBA compiler?

Comment: What happens if you call it as « ret = c.strange("", v(LBound(v))) » instead of using Call?

Comment: Nope, don't have any inside knowledge, just happened to have played with the language a lot. You'll be pleased to know this bug applies to the standalone VB6 as well. :) And here's [one more bug for you to enjoy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183353/how-do-i-determine-if-an-array-is-initialized-in-vb6/183356#183356).

Comment: Thanks for the detective work. I'm convinced! For once I get to blame a bona-fide compiler bug...

Comment: Reproduced in Office 2010... `VarPtr()` confirms that it is indeed the pointer to the actual value in the array :(