# VBA Check whether array returned is 2D or 1D?

Tags: excel, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to return the number of dimensions of a (Variant) variable passed to it in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901991/how-to-return-the-number-of-dimensions-of-a-variant-variable-passed-to-it-in-v)

Is there any way of checking whether a VBA array is 2D or 1D? I cannot use `isnumeric` on `lbound(x,2)` because I get a subscript-out-of-range exception.

EDIT I also cannot use `iserror(lbound(x,2))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901991/how-to-return-the-number-of-dimensions-of-a-variant-variable-passed-to-it-in-v

This is the only way

Comment: if the array was already populated you could try a `Join` with error checking. Only 1D array can be joined