# Single Dimension Variant Arrays VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

In general I have a good macro for change management for a single value and now can write one for an multi dimensional array but need to be able to differential between without the use of error handling.

Is there any other work around for when the target is only one cell? the error handling below handles the issue but I consider it to be "sloppy." 
Suggestions are appreciated on a better method.

```
Sub Dims(target As Variant)

Dim varData As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

varData = target

On Error GoTo Err

For i = 1 To UBound(varData, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(varData, 2)
        Debug.Print i, j, varData(i, j)
    Next j
Next i

Err:
If Err.Number = 13 Then
    Debug.Print target.Value
ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " just occured."
ElseIf Err.Number <> 13 And Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Err No.= "; Err.Number
Else
    Debug.Print "No Error"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So if the Target is just one cell, don't run the macro? Just add `If target.count = 1 Then Exit Sub` to the top

Comment: Use another function to count the number of dimensions: [How to return the number of dimensions of a (Variant) variable passed to it in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901991/how-to-return-the-number-of-dimensions-of-a-variant-variable-passed-to-it-in-v)

Comment: thanks for the "target.count" I forgot that targets are ranges. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a if then statement to run one way if target.count =1 and another if target.count>1