# How to remove repeating elements from two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, dataframe, excel-formula

I have two columns for example:

```
A      B

1      2

1      3

1      5

3      4

2      1

4      3
```

I want the output to come like this:

```
A      B

1      2

1      3

1      5

3      4
```

I want to remove the data which gets repeated from 1 column to another. Is there any function in excel to do so?

Comment: By using the "remove duplicates" button?? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-remove-duplicates-00e35bea-b46a-4d5d-b28e-66a552dc138d

Comment: Include your attempt/research where you got stuck. @B001ᛦ, that's not going to work in this case unfortunately

Comment: _that's not going to work in this case..._ Why not? Because of having duplicates in 2 columns? @JvdV

Comment: @B001ᛦ, have you tried it =)?. Simply using remove duplicates over these two column generate zero duplicates to remove.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Because OP's not asking to remove the duplicates *per column* - for which you just run "Remove Duplicates" on each column and click "Continue with the current selection" instead of "Expand the selection" - but rather to remove all duplicates *pairs*, regardless of order - see how the 5th row `2 | 1` gets removed as a duplicate of the 1st row `1 | 2`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will load the Range into an Array.  It will then go through each Row of the Array in turn, sort the values in the Row, and compare that against already-processed rows.

If it is new, it is added to the Output and Processed Rows - if it already exists then it is ignored.  Finally, it will output the array back into the original Range

This is *slightly* more complicated than it needs to be, to preserve the order of elements in the first row for each combination - a simpler method would have been to sort the columns of each row into order and then just use "Remove Duplicates" on the whole thing.

The `ArrayDimension` code is nabbed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44629011/9290986), so please consider wandering over to upvote [Emeka Eya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7752204/emeka-eya)

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateRows(Target As Range, Optional Permutations As Boolean = False)
'Target: Range to remove duplicate rows from
'Permutations: If FALSE then ignore the order of elements in the row
    Dim InputArray As Variant, ArrayPointer As Long

    If Permutations Then
        'This is just a normal RemoveDuplicates
        ReDim InputArray(0 To (Target.Columns.Count - 1))

        For ArrayPointer = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
            InputArray(ArrayPointer - 1) = ArrayPointer
        Next ArrayPointer

        Target.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=InputArray, Header:=xlNo
    Else
        Dim RowArray As Variant, ArrayBinding As Long
        Dim OutputArray As Variant, OutputRow As Variant
        Dim ProcessedRows As Variant, CurrentRow As String
        Dim TransferColumn As Long

        InputArray = Target.Value
        ArrayBinding = LBound(InputArray, 1)
        OutputRow = ArrayBinding

        'Empty array the same size as the input, and a 1D array the same height
        ReDim OutputArray(LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1), LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1))
        ReDim ProcessedRows(LBound(InputArray, 1) To UBound(InputArray, 1))

        For ArrayPointer = ArrayBinding To UBound(InputArray, 1)
            'Get 1D array containing just this specific row
            RowArray = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(InputArray, ArrayPointer + 1 - ArrayBinding, 0)))

            'Sort the Array and Flatten into a string for Searching
            CurrentRow = SortArrayAndFlatten(RowArray)

            'If the row is new, then add it
            If UBound(Filter(ProcessedRows, CurrentRow)) < 0 Then
                For TransferColumn = LBound(RowArray) To UBound(RowArray)
                    OutputArray(OutputRow, TransferColumn) = RowArray(TransferColumn)
                Next TransferColumn
                'Mark the row as already processed
                ProcessedRows(OutputRow) = CurrentRow
                OutputRow = OutputRow + 1
            End If
        Next ArrayPointer

        Target.Clear
        Target.Value = OutputArray
    End If
End Sub

Private Function SortArrayAndFlatten(ByVal TargetArray As Variant) As String
'This will output a String of the Sorted Elements of the Array
    If Not IsArray(TargetArray) Then Exit Function
'Only work on 1D arrays
    If ArrayDimension(TargetArray) > 1 Then Exit Function

    Dim OuterLoop As Long, InnerLoop As Long, StoppingPoint As Long, HoldingBucket As Variant, NoSwaps As Boolean
    StoppingPoint = LBound(TargetArray) + 1
    For OuterLoop = UBound(TargetArray) To StoppingPoint Step -1
        NoSwaps = True
        For InnerLoop = OuterLoop To StoppingPoint Step -1
            If TargetArray(InnerLoop) > TargetArray(InnerLoop - 1) Then
                'Swap the elements
                HoldingBucket = TargetArray(InnerLoop)
                TargetArray(InnerLoop) = TargetArray(InnerLoop - 1)
                TargetArray(InnerLoop - 1) = HoldingBucket
                NoSwaps = False
            End If
        Next InnerLoop
        If NoSwaps Then Exit For
    Next OuterLoop
    SortArrayAndFlatten = Join(TargetArray, "|")
End Function

Function ArrayDimension(ByRef ArrayX As Variant) As Long
    Dim i As Long, a As String, arDim As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    i = 0
    Do
        a = CStr(ArrayX(0, i))
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            arDim = i
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Do
        Else
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
    If arDim = 0 Then arDim = 1
    ArrayDimension = arDim
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim strA_I As String, strB_I As String, strA_J As String, strB_J As String, strDelete As String
    Dim varDelete As Variant

    strDelete = ""

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            strA_I = .Range("A" & i).Value
            strB_I = .Range("B" & i).Value

            For j = i + 1 To LastRow

                strA_J = .Range("A" & j).Value
                strB_J = .Range("B" & j).Value

                If ((strA_I = strA_J) Or (strA_I = strB_J)) And ((strB_I = strA_J) Or (strB_I = strB_J)) Then

                    If strDelete = "" Then
                        strDelete = j
                    Else
                        strDelete = strDelete & "," & j
                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

        varDelete = Split(strDelete, ",")

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

            For j = LBound(varDelete) To UBound(varDelete)

                If i = varDelete(j) Then

                    Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    Exit For

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy to do, ***but***.... There's a minor issue, **we don't have a complete definition of the problem.**

> "I want to remove the data which gets repeated from 1 column to another."

What happens when left and right columns are identical?  This is presently undefined.

---

Start from the bottom row and concatenate the left and right column with a delimeter.  If desired, test them to see if left and right are identical to each other and figure out what to do if they are; do you keep one? Toss both?.  If kept, this string becomes the first element in an expanding array.

If you kept the first pair then you'll keep this pair as well, so swap the columns to build the reverse string and put it in the second element of the array.

Move up to the next row.  Test for equivalency if desired, build your string. Only add the string to the array if it is a unique.

Create the reverse string, and add it to the array if unique.

Delete the row if either string exists in the array.

Repeat all the way to the top.

Answer (score 0):

If one has the Dyanmic Array formula UNIQUE then use this:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE(IF($A$1:$A$6<$B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6)&"|"&IF($A$1:$A$6>=$B$1:$B$6,$A$1:$A$6,$B$1:$B$6)),"|",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A1)-1)*999+1,999))
```

Put that in the first output cell and drag over one column.

[image]