# How do I make a VB6 variant array with UBound < LBound?

Tags: arrays, vb6, variant

I'm trying to get rid of dependencies on SCRRUN.DLL in a VB6 application.  One of the things it's currently being used for is its Dictionary class.  The Dictionary class has a Keys function that is supposed to return an array of the keys in the dictionary.  I did a little experimentation to see what happens if there are no keys in the dictionary:

```
Dim D As Dictionary
Set D = New Dictionary
Dim K() As Variant
K = D.Keys
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

I was expecting "subscript out of range", or something similar, but instead I was informed that the LBound is 0 and the UBound is -1.

So, how can I create a Variant array that has LBound 0 and UBound -1?

I've tried just using an uninitialized variant array:

```
Dim K() as Variant
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

But of course that throws "Subscript out of range", as I would expect.  So does erasing an uninitialized array:

```
Dim K() as Variant
Erase K
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

As does erasing an initialized array:

```
Dim K() As Variant
ReDim K(0 To 0)
Erase K
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

I also tried just redimming to 0 and -1, strange as that may seem:

```
Dim K() As Variant
ReDim K(0 To -1)
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

But that also gives "subscript out of range".

Poking around on the web a bit, I found the following trick:

```
Dim K() As String
K = Split(vbNullString)
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

And that actually does give an array with LBound 0 and UBound -1! Unforunately, it's a String array, whereas I need a Variant array.  I can't very well individually copy the Strings from one array to Variants in another array, because, well, 0 to -1 and all.

Does anyone know how to make such an array, Variant() with LBound 0 and UBound -1, without using SCRRUN.DLL? Preferably also using only built-in VB6 stuff, but if you can do it if you're allowed to use some external thing (other than SCRRUN.DLL), I'm all ears.  Thanks.

Comment: As you noticed in your experiments, you can sometimes run into an unitialized array which will give you the "Subscript out of range" errors -- this is different than an initialized, but empty, array. You may also find this answer to be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/444810/137646

Comment: +1 for good research shown in your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262675%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) function:

```
Dim K()
K = Array()
MsgBox UBound(K)
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, answering my own question (but using OLEAUT32.DLL; I'd still be interested in any solutions that are pure built-in VB6):

```
Private Declare Function SafeArrayCreateVector Lib "OLEAUT32.DLL" ( _
    ByVal vt As VbVarType, ByVal lLbound As Long, ByVal cElements As Long) _
    As Variant()

Private Const VT_VARIANT As Long = 12
```

(...)

```
Dim K() As Variant
K = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 0)
MsgBox LBound(K) & ", " & UBound(K)
```

Comment: Here is an in-depth discussion how to construct empty arrays of various types: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?736285-VB6-Returning-Detecting-Empty-Arrays