# vb6 how to resize dynamic arrays

Tags: arrays, dynamic, vb6

In vb6 I have an dynamic array defined like this because I don't know how many values to be added while running the program

```
Private myrray() As String
```

Now I have problems to redimension this array. I have tried to following

```
Dim Upper As Integer
Upper = UBound(myArray) ' here I get the runtime error
If Err.Number Then
  Upper = 0
Else
Upper = UBound(myArray) + 1
End If
```

The problem is that the **upper()**-function always gives me **runtime-error 9 "index outside the valid area**

I also tried an other way, here I become the same error but in the else-Block:

```
Dim Upper As Integer
If IsEmpty(myArray) Then
  Upper = 0
Else
  Upper = UBound(myArray) + 1 'here I get the same error in this line
End If
```

Later I will use **Upper** to redimensionze my array like this to add a new value:

```
ReDim Preserve myArray(Upper)
myArray(Upper) = "new text"
```

Does anyone know why and how I can solve this problem or tell me an other way to redimensionize an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume a typo: you declare `myrray` not `myArray`)

`Private myArray() As String`

This gives you an uninitialized array, i.e. one with no dimensions at all & your issue is that you cannot call array functions like `UBound`/`LBound` on an array in that state.

Your options are:

- Set its size to 0 `redim myArray(0)` when your application starts
- [Detect and handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183353/how-do-i-determine-if-an-array-is-initialized-in-vb6) the uninitialized state and handle it accordingly

Comment: You can use `myArray = Split(vbNullString)` to get an initialized but empty array.