# VBA define zero length 2Dim Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a UDF in Excel VBA that returns a 2 dimensional array, in certain cases the length of the array should be zero. How do you define a zero length array?

The below returns a compiler error;

```
Dim empty_array(1 to 1,1 to -1)
```

Comment: Dim myArray(,) as WhateverYourDataTypeIs e.g. Dim myArray(,) as Integer

Comment: Try `Dim var As Variant: var = Array(Array(), Array())`

Comment: @Absinthe That would be VB.NET.

Comment: Would it not be enough to return an unresized array? Excel will display `#VALUE!` in all cells, but I believe it would do the same if you passed a `(1 To -1)` array. If you mean to consume that array later with code as opposed to putting it on a sheet, you might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/q/183353/11683.

Comment: @GSerg, I agree, returning a CVErr makes sense and it is consistent with the user's past excel experience

Comment: Not a `CVErr`, just an empty array (`Dim empty_array()`).

Comment: @GSerg - Nope, that's VBA syntax for sure. I've used it hundreds of times.

Comment: @Absinthe Excel 2010 VBA throws a syntax error with that

Comment: @GSerg - Apologies, your right, sorry... too many programming languages ;)